# Why does sudo change the PATH?

Tags: path, environment-variables, sudo

This is the `PATH` variable without sudo:

```
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sh 
/opt/local/ruby/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

This is the `PATH` variable with sudo:

```
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

As far as I can tell, `sudo` is supposed to leave `PATH` untouched. What's going on? How do I change this? (This is on Ubuntu 8.04).

UPDATE: as far as I can see, none of the scripts started as root change `PATH` in any way.

From `man sudo`:

> To prevent command spoofing, sudo
>   checks ``.'' and ``'' (both denoting
>   current directory) last when searching
>   for a command in the user's PATH (if
>   one or both are in the PATH). **Note,
>   however, that the actual PATH
>   environment variable is not modified
>   and is passed unchanged to the program
>   that sudo executes.**

Comment: Does root have anything that sets PATH in .bashrc? This is assuming that since you're on Linux, sh is really bash.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-pathc || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su || http://superuser.com/questions/98686/passing-path-through-sudo

Answer (score 254):

This is <del>an annoying function</del> *a feature* of sudo on many distributions.

To work around this "problem" on ubuntu I do
the following in my ~/.bashrc

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

Note the above will work for commands that don't reset the $PATH themselves.
However `su' resets it's $PATH so you must use -p to tell it not to. I.E.:

```
sudo su -p
```

Comment: This "annoying function" prevents you from getting trojaned. I say forcing a specific $PATH is a feature, not a bug---it makes you write out the full path to a program that's outside the $PATH.

Comment: Yeah, but it's totally counterintuitive.  It probably fools the good guys more than the bad guys.

Comment: I'm confused. Chris, do you mean, "it makes you write out the full path to a program that's _inside_ the $PATH" ? Or do you mean "...that's outside the default/secure $PATH" ?

Comment: Not only is it counterintuitive, it's incorrectly documented. Reading the man pages for sudo, and comparing the config against a Fedora box, I thought the path should be preserved. Indeed, "sudo -V" even says "Environment variables to preserve: PATH".

Comment: This answer doesn't work any longer (ubuntu 9.10, the karmic koala one). Please, update!

Comment: @Jason: The latter. (Sorry, I wasn't alerted to your response, probably because it didn't start with "@Chris"; I only knew about it because this thread was mentioned in chat lately.)

Comment: Note that this alias will screw up some things, such as "sudo -s"

Comment: it's annoying. period. if it could 'get you trojaned' by sudo it could get you trojaned the same without it. granted, harder, but if you are running code from the wrong place even with your regular user, then things are already bad enough.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs yeah, the documentation ads insult to the annoyance. that's why i respect openBSD for treating documentation like code. that would have been a blocking bug there. on ubuntu...

Comment: Don't alias sudo; see answer from @Jacob about Defaults env_reset.

Comment: This alias is using an un-quoted variable substitution which runs as root.  (it is also causing two unnecessary fork/execs every command you run with it) Even if security isn't that important on your box, this just feels evil to me.  See the solution using !secure_path and env_keep.

Comment: Why is this voted #1? This answer doesn't answer OP's question as to _why_ sudo changes the path, and it provides a questionable "solution" without explaining the potential drawbacks! The usefulness of this feature is opinion-based, and should be up to the reader to decide given an unbiased list of pros and cons.

Answer (score 126):

In case someone else runs accross this and wants to just disable all path variable changing for all users.
Access your sudoers file by using the command:`visudo`.  You should see the following line somewhere:

> Defaults        env_reset

which you should add the following on the next line

> Defaults        !secure_path

secure_path is enabled by default.  This option specifies what to make $PATH when sudoing.  The exclamation mark disables the feature.

Comment: another way: `Defaults    env_keep = "PATH"`

Comment: Defaults !secure_path worked great for me on modern systems; on an old ubuntu 8.04 box, Defaults env_keep = "PATH" did the trick.

Comment: Instead of disabling the secure_path you can add to it. For example in my case I added the line "Defaults secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/some/custom/directory" where "some/custom/directory" is the path that I needed to make available to  sudo.

Comment: @HectorCorrea solution is the better way IMO.

Answer (score 33):

`PATH` is an environment variable, and as such is by default reset by sudo.

You need special permissions to be permitted to do this.

From `man sudo`

```
       -E  The -E (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset
           option in sudoers(5)).  It is only available when either the match-
           ing command has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in sudo-
           ers(5).
```

```
       Environment variables to be set for the command may also be passed on
       the command line in the form of VAR=value, e.g.
       LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pkg/lib.  Variables passed on the command
       line are subject to the same restrictions as normal environment vari-
       ables with one important exception.  If the setenv option is set in
       sudoers, the command to be run has the SETENV tag set or the command
       matched is ALL, the user may set variables that would overwise be for-
       bidden.  See sudoers(5) for more information.
```

An Example of usage:

```
cat >> test.sh
env | grep "MYEXAMPLE" ;
^D
```

```bash
sh test.sh 
MYEXAMPLE=1 sh test.sh
# MYEXAMPLE=1
MYEXAMPLE=1 sudo sh test.sh 
MYEXAMPLE=1 sudo MYEXAMPLE=2 sh test.sh 
# MYEXAMPLE=2
```

#### update

```
man 5 sudoers : 

     env_reset       If set, sudo will reset the environment to only contain
                       the LOGNAME, SHELL, USER, USERNAME and the SUDO_* vari-
                       ables.  Any variables in the caller's environment that
                       match the env_keep and env_check lists are then added.
                       The default contents of the env_keep and env_check
                       lists are displayed when sudo is run by root with the
                       -V option.  If sudo was compiled with the SECURE_PATH
                       option, its value will be used for the PATH environment
                       variable.  This flag is on by default.
```

So may need to check that this is/is not compiled in.

It is by default in **Gentoo**

```bash
# ( From the build Script )
....
ROOTPATH=$(cleanpath /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/bin${ROOTPATH:+:${ROOTPATH}})
....
econf --with-secure-path="${ROOTPATH}"
```

Answer (score 18):

Looks like this bug has been around for quite a while! Here are some bug references you may find helpful (and may want to subscribe to / vote up, hint, hint...):

---

[Debian bug #85123 ("sudo: SECURE_PATH still can't be overridden") (from 2001!)](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=85123)

> It seems that Bug#20996 is still present in this version of sudo.  The
>   changelog says that it can be overridden at runtime but I haven't yet
>   discovered how.

They mention putting something like this in your sudoers file:

```
Defaults secure_path="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
```

but when I do that in Ubuntu 8.10 at least, it gives me this error:

```
visudo: unknown defaults entry `secure_path' referenced near line 10
```

---

[Ubuntu bug #50797 ("sudo built with --with-secure-path is problematic")](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/50797)

> Worse still, as far as I can tell, it
>   is impossible to respecify secure_path
>   in the sudoers file. So if, for
>   example, you want to offer your users
>   easy access to something under /opt,
>   you must recompile sudo.
>
> ---
>
> Yes. There *needs* to be a way to
>   override this "feature" without having
>   to recompile. Nothing worse then
>   security bigots telling you what's
>   best for your environment and then not
>   giving you a way to turn it off.
>
> ---
>
> This is really annoying. It might be
>   wise to keep current behavior by
>   default for security reasons, but
>   there should be a way of overriding it
>   other than recompiling from source
>   code! Many people ARE in need of PATH
>   inheritance. I wonder why no
>   maintainers look into it, which seems
>   easy to come up with an acceptable
>   solution.
>
> ---
>
> I worked around it like this:
>
> ```
> mv /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo.orig
> ```
>
> then create a file /usr/bin/sudo containing the following:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> /usr/bin/sudo.orig env PATH=$PATH "$@"
> ```
>
> then your regular sudo works just like the non secure-path sudo

---

[Ubuntu bug #192651 ("sudo path is always reset")](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/192651/)

> Given that a duplicate of this bug was
>   originally filed in July 2006, I'm not
>   clear how long an ineffectual env_keep
>   has been in operation. Whatever the
>   merits of forcing users to employ
>   tricks such as that listed above,
>   surely the man pages for sudo and
>   sudoers should reflect the fact that
>   options to modify the PATH are
>   effectively redundant.
>
> Modifying documentation to reflect
>   actual execution is non destabilising
>   and very helpful.

---

[Ubuntu bug #226595 ("impossible to retain/specify PATH")](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/226595)

> I need to be able to run sudo with
>   additional non-std binary folders in
>   the PATH. Having already added my
>   requirements to /etc/environment I was
>   surprised when I got errors about
>   missing commands when running them
>   under sudo.....
>
> I tried the following to fix this
>   without sucess:
>
> 1. Using the "`sudo -E`" option - did not work. My existing PATH was still reset by sudo
> 2. Changing "`Defaults env_reset`" to "`Defaults !env_reset`" in /etc/sudoers -- also did not work (even when combined with sudo -E)
> 3. Uncommenting `env_reset` (e.g. "`#Defaults env_reset`") in /etc/sudoers -- also did not work.
> 4. Adding '`Defaults env_keep += "PATH"`' to /etc/sudoers -- also did not work.
>
> Clearly - despite the man
>   documentation - sudo is completely
>   hardcoded regarding PATH and does not
>   allow any flexibility regarding
>   retaining the users PATH. Very
>   annoying as I can't run non-default
>   software under root permissions using
>   sudo.

Answer (score 15):

This seemed to work for me

```
sudo -i
```

which takes on the non-sudo `PATH`

Comment: 'sudo -i' doesn't help on Ubuntu (I checked Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS). $PATH is still modified by sudo.

Answer (score 11):

I think it is in fact desirable to have sudo reset the PATH: otherwise an attacker having compromised your user account could put backdoored versions of all kinds of tools on your users' PATH, and they would be executed when using sudo.

(of course having sudo reset the PATH is not a complete solution to these kinds of problems, but it helps)

This is indeed what happens when you use

```
Defaults env_reset
```

in /etc/sudoers without using `exempt_group` or `env_keep`.

This is also convenient because you can add directories that are only useful for root (such as `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`) to the sudo path without adding them to your users' paths. To specify the path to be used by sudo:

```
Defaults secure_path="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin"
```

Comment: an attacker who gains acccess to a sudoer account can do even worse things.

Comment: A decent advice. On ubuntu 12.04 Server, a similar setting is default.

Answer (score 7):

Works now using sudo from the karmic repositories. Details from my configuration:

```
root@sphinx:~# cat /etc/sudoers | grep -v -e '^$' -e '^#'
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/grub-1.96/sbin:/opt/grub-1.96/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
root@sphinx:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted universe

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security main restricted universe

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted universe
root@sphinx:~# 

root@sphinx:~# cat /etc/apt/preferences 
Package: sudo
Pin: release a=karmic-security
Pin-Priority: 990

Package: sudo
Pin: release a=karmic-updates
Pin-Priority: 960

Package: sudo
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 930

Package: *
Pin: release a=jaunty-security
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release a=jaunty-updates
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=jaunty
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: release a=karmic-security
Pin-Priority: 450

Package: *
Pin: release a=karmic-updates
Pin-Priority: 250

Package: *
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 50
root@sphinx:~# apt-cache policy sudo
sudo:
  Installed: 1.7.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.7.0-1ubuntu2
  Package pin: 1.7.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.7.0-1ubuntu2 930
         50 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.9p17-1ubuntu3 930
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Packages
root@sphinx:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/grub-1.96/sbin:/opt/grub-1.96/bin
root@sphinx:~# exit
exit
abolte@sphinx:~$ echo $PATH
/home/abolte/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/grub-1.96/sbin:/opt/grub-1.96/bin:/opt/chromium-17593:/opt/grub-1.96/sbin:/opt/grub-1.96/bin:/opt/xpra-0.0.6/bin
abolte@sphinx:~$
```

It's wonderful to finally have this solved without using a hack.

Comment: Perhaps you would consider rewriting this to indicate how somebody with a clean Karmic install might update their config to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
# cat .bash_profile | grep PATH
PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
export PATH

# cat /etc/sudoers | grep Defaults
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep = "SOME_PARAM1 SOME_PARAM2 ... PATH"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just comment out "Defaults env_reset" in /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 3):

Just edit `env_keep` in `/etc/sudoers`

It looks something like this:

`Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASURE MENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL L ANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"`

Just append PATH at the end, so after the change it would look like this:

`Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASURE MENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL L ANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE PATH"`

Close the terminal and then open again.

Comment: Wait PATH needs 2 **? Why does PATH need **?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai It was formatted as bold (in markdown), but someone (stack overflow won't let me point fingers) edited it to mark it up as code.

Answer (score 2):

Secure_path is your friend, but if you want to exempt yourself from secure_path just do

```
sudo visudo
```

And append

```
Defaults exempt_group=your_goup
```

If you want to exempt a bunch of users create a group, add all the users to it, and use that as your exempt_group. man 5 sudoers for more.

Answer (score 1):

the recommended solution in the comments on the OpenSUSE distro suggests to change:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

to:

```
Defaults !env_reset
```

and then presumably to comment out the following line which isn't needed:

```
Defaults env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASURE    MENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL L    ANGUAGE LINGUAS XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
```

Answer (score 1):

comment out both "Default env_reset" and "Default secure_path ..." in /etc/sudores file works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also move your file in a sudoers used directory :

```
    sudo mv $HOME/bash/script.sh /usr/sbin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Er, it's not really a test if you don't add something to your path:

```
bill@bill-desktop:~$ ls -l /opt/pkg/bin
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   28 2009-01-22 18:58 foo
bill@bill-desktop:~$ which foo
/opt/pkg/bin/foo
bill@bill-desktop:~$ sudo su
root@bill-desktop:/home/bill# which foo
root@bill-desktop:/home/bill#
```

Answer (score 0):

The PATH will be reset when using su or sudo by the definition of ENV_SUPATH, and ENV_PATH defined in /etc/login.defs

Answer (score 0):

**$PATH** is an environment variable and it means that value of **$PATH** can differ for another users.

When you are doing login into your system then your profile setting decide the value of the **$PATH**.

Now, lets take a look:-

```
User       |        Value of $PATH
--------------------------
root                /var/www
user1               /var/www/user1
user2               /var/www/html/private
```

Suppose that these are the values of $PATH for different user. Now when you are executing any command with sudo then in actual meaning **root** user executes that command .

You can confirm by executing these commands on terminal :-

```
user@localhost$ whoami
username
user@localhost$ sudo whoami
root
user@localhost$
```

This is the reason. I think its clear to you.

Comment: so I would expect this to hold for sudo -u or sudo su - but plain sudo seems to do this just for access to sbin?  it more often than not means adding riders to root's .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

It may be counter-intuitive but the first time it happened to me, I knew what was going on. Believe me, you don't want root running someone else's PATH

"Hey root? Can you help me, something is wrong" and he comes over and sudo's from my shell and I wrote a "${HOME}/bin/ls" shell script that first gives me superuser privileges, and then calls the real /bin/ls.

```
# personal ls
usermod -a -G sudo ${USER}
/bin/ls
```

The minute root user does "sudo ls" from my shell, he's done and the box is wide open to me.