# Using Ruby Enterprise Edition, gems are not installed where I would expect

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-enterprise-edition

I have just installed Ruby Enterprise Edition and am installing some gems for it. Stock Ruby 1.8.6 is also installed on the server.

I have added `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin` to my `PATH` a head of `/usr/bin` where `ruby` and `gem` live.

`which gem` confirms this:

`/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin/gem`

However, when I install gems like this:

`gem install some_gem`

They end up in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/` instead of `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/`.

But if I use `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin/gem install some_gem` it *does* go into REE's gem directory.

I don't get it. Is there some config option I have to change? I *am* using sudo here. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a good explanation of what's going on here:

[sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

This assumes you're using Ubuntu. sudo does change the path under ubuntu.

The gem you have in /usr/bin/ is probably a symlink to /usr/bin/gem1.8. What I did was symlink ruby-enterprise's gem to /usr/bin/ree-gem like this:

sudo ln -s /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin/gem /usr/bin/ree-gem

then I just use:

sudo ree-gem install some_gem

to install gems specifically for ree. If you're not using the ruby 1.8.6 rubygem, you can symlink REE's gem to /usr/bin/gem instead:

sudo ln -s /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem

Comment: Wow, very interesting! I am using Ubuntu. I did not know that sudo on Ubuntu didn't change the path. That is bizare.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I used to a similar problem is to set up an alias to your REE gem command.

I.e.

```
alias reegem='/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin/gem'
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the solution I used on Ubuntu here:
http://groups.google.com/group/emm-ruby/browse_thread/thread/d0c685bbd096823a#msg_effa7d6ad42c541c

There were some additional steps to get it working beyond what was described in the Ruby Enterprise Edition documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation for why it's setup like this for REE:   http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_how_ree_installs_itself_into_the_system

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jack Chu's helpful symlink above, might I suggest:

sudo ln -s /opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/rake /usr/bin/ree-rake

so you can sudo ree-rake gems:install