# no such file to load -- rails/cli under Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, ruby-enterprise-edition

On a VPS I tried to install Ruby. Because of memory exhaustion problems, we were unable to compile ruby 1.9.2 , and we decided to give Ruby Enterprise Edition a try. This compiled without complaining about memory problems.
Next, we install rubygems, and to test that it's working, I installed `haml`. It worked.

The next step was to install rails, via `gem install rails`. The version it downloaded was the latest, 3.0.5. Installation went ok. However, when I try to create a new project, I receive:

`no such file to load -- rails/cli`

Looking around on the internet, people said this is a problem related to older versions of rails, and some of them suggested to do a `gem clean`. I didn't have any other version of ruby before, therefore, no other version of rails. But, just to be sure, I did a `gem clean` and then reinstalled rails. The problem persists.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your running the gem binary that Ruby Enterprise Edition installed.  So rather than:

gem install rails

it would be something like:

sudo /opt/ruby-enterprise-X.X.X/bin/gem install rails

To save having to type the whole path each time, you can symlink the REE binaries with something like:

sudo ln -sf /opt/ruby-enterprise-X.X.X/bin/* /usr/bin/.

Comment: more detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588934/using-ruby-enterprise-edition-gems-are-not-installed-where-i-would-expect