# delayed_job not picking up the rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, delayed-job

Followed this question about [delayed_job and monit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226302/how-to-monitor-delayedjob-with-monit)

Its working on my development machine. But whenever I try to run on production, it just dies with following on delayed_job.log

```
*** Starting job worker delayed_job host:mail.welcometonewnepal.com pid:356
#<Mysql::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)>
*** Starting job worker delayed_job host:mail.welcometonewnepal.com pid:441
#<Mysql::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)>
*** Starting job worker delayed_job host:mail.welcometonewnepal.com pid:448
#<Mysql::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)>
```

And I m going to run in production env

```
ruby script/delayed_job start -e production
```

Still it errors out. I m noticing that this is due to the environment not set so that it tries to pick up the development environment.

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:365:in `read': No such file or directory - /home/millisami/rails_apps/wnn_finale/config/environments/-e.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Why isn't the environment parameter not set properly?

Comment: cite makes a good point. What does your script/delayed_job file look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be worng here, but are you using [this gist](http://gist.github.com/104314) as script/delayed_job? If so, it doesn't need the "-e" - `simply calling script/delayed_job start production` or chaning the line that starts with `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` (replacing "development" with "production") should be sufficient.

If you still get errors from MySQL afterwards, you should double check your username and password.

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
ruby RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to help people finding this question and the old answers: the script doesn't accept the environment parameter any more: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

Try `script/delayed_job start -- production`. I don't think you pass the environment to DJ the same way as you would to `script/server`. This answer is specific to the `delayed_job` file that we use, I'm looking for a gist of it.

EDIT: Here is the [gist](http://gist.github.com/54682) of the file we use.