# Starting delayed_job at startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job with capistrano and would like a way to start delayed_job on startup of the web application using the 'script/delayed_job start'.  This way capistrano can restart it on deploy.  If the server gets rebooted then my delayed_jobs should start up with the project.

How can I do this?
Should I be looking at doing this in the environment files or as an initializer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should create one recipe with the restart command.

```
namespace :delayed_job do 
    desc "Restart the delayed_job process"
    task :restart, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job restart"
    end
end
```

Then you add it to be executed at the end of your deployment.

```
after "deploy:update_code", "delayed_job:restart"
```

Comment: I've already got this recipe in my capistrano and it's working.  My question was more related to rebooting the server.  Currently I've done a work around where on boot I just run a script in my init.d and start the delayed_job daemon.  It would be nice to have that as part of my application though.

Comment: You could use [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) to manage the process and boot it automatically when the machine boots.

Comment: delayed_job has its own recipes.rb file that has the above task pretty much exactly, plus delayed_job:start and delayed_job:stop tasks.

Comment: Hi @Ryan: i noticed this too, but i am stuck as to how to include/require those inside my `deploy.rb`. Just `require `delayed_job'` does not work for me (i am using the version from git).

Comment: Using rails 3 I found that I needed to do require 'bundler/setup' in deploy.rb before require 'delayed_job/recipes'

Answer (score 34):

In combination with the capistrano restart recipe it's quite convenient to use cron to also start the delayed_job daemon at startup using the special `@reboot` time in a crontab:

```
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/app && RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart'
```

And it's even more convenient together with [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to configure a scheduled task:

```
job_type :envcommand, 'cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment :task'

every :reboot do
  envcommand 'script/delayed_job restart'
end
```

Not sure if all implementation of cron actually only run `@reboot` at system startup but at least Ubuntu seams to only run them at start up and not whenever the cron daemon start or restart. If you pass `restart` to `script/delayed_job` it will probably work in either case.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Works on Ubuntu 12.04 just fine. Love crontabs.

Answer (score 20):

A bit late to this question, but version 2.1.4 of delayed_job has capistrano recipes:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Rails-3-and-Capistrano

It's Damien Mathieu's answer, but already part of the delayed_job gem.

Answer (score 7):

This now works with both Rails 2 and 3:

In deploy.rb, add the following lines:

```
require "delayed/recipes"
set :rails_env, 'production' #added for delayed_job
before "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:stop"
after  "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:stop",  "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to boot & monitor delayed_job with monit: 
[How to monitor delayed_job with monit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226302/how-to-monitor-delayed-job-with-monit)