# Starting delayed_job at startup with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I want to start script/delayed_job start on my production when i will start my rails server.
Is there anyway i can do that?

EDIT::

I have added this line to my config/initializers/delayed_job.rb .

```
Delayed::Worker.new.start
```

But my delayed job server is not starting when i am running my rails applicaiton.
Is there any other solution??

Comment: How do you start your rails server? Change that sw to also start dj.

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem?

Comment: Add a cron job to run your worker on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend deploying your app with Capistrano and defining a after:deploy hook to start/restart DJ at every deploy.

I would also recommend using Resque over DelayedJob, as the latter has tendencies to just die without any reason, and usually requires a Monit/God monitoring and restarting it.

```
namespace :delayed_job do
  desc "Start delayed_job process" 
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job start #{rails_env}" 
  end

  desc "Stop delayed_job process" 
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job stop #{rails_env}" 
  end

  desc "Restart delayed_job process" 
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job restart #{rails_env}" 
  end
end

after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start" 
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop" 
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
```

Comment: i have already set up that thing with capistrano but now i want to start delayed_job when i will start my rails application server or apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an init.d file, but I would recommend either monit or god.  God is ruby, so it is familiar, but that also means it leaks a bit.  If you are going to run God, I recommend a cron job to restart it.  [This is a VERY good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226302/how-to-monitor-delayed-job-with-monit) on configuring monit on your server.

We went the God route, but if we had it to do over again - we would do monit.

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
Delayed::Worker.new.start
```

in your initializers directory (create a new ".rb" file in there and it'll start with your app)

Comment: i have added this line on my delayed_job.rb file in config/initializers. And started server with ruby script/server -e production for production. But it's not starting my delayed_job server.