# Missing PID file when using a process manager to start delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, bluepill

I am using BluePill to manage processes such as delayed job for Rails.  In the BluePill log, I am getting this message:

```
W, [2010-09-27T01:23:20.447053 #19441]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] pid_file /srv/fsg_distro/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid does not exist or cannot be read
W, [2010-09-27T01:23:20.447368 #19441]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] Executing start command: ruby script/delayed_job -e production start
I, [2010-09-27T01:23:20.469165 #19441]  INFO -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] Going from down => starting
```

So it's claiming that a pid file is missing, which it is, but shouldn't that pid be created when BluePill starts the Delayed Job process?

**Update**
To be a bit more clear about this error, I can successfully run the command manually but Bluepill fails to run the start command.  When I run it manually, it looks like this:

```
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro/current$ /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/ruby /srv/fsg_distro/current/script/delayed_job start
delayed_job: process with pid 17564 started.
```

When I run it with Bluepill it looks like this:

```
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:13.943136 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] pid_file /srv/fsg_distro/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid does not exist or cannot be read
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:13.943391 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] pid_file /srv/fsg_distro/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid does not exist or cannot be read
I, [2010-10-03T21:24:13.943811 #17326]  INFO -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] Going from starting => down
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:14.945274 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] pid_file /srv/fsg_distro/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid does not exist or cannot be read
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:14.945495 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] pid_file /srv/fsg_distro/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid does not exist or cannot be read
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:14.945826 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] Executing start command: /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/ruby /srv/fsg_distro/current/script/delayed_job start
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:15.049261 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] Start command execution returned non-zero exit code:
W, [2010-10-03T21:24:15.049491 #17326]  WARN -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] {:stderr=>"", :exit_code=>1, :stdout=>""} 
I, [2010-10-03T21:24:15.049947 #17326]  INFO -- : [fsg_distro:delayed_job] Going from down => starting
```

My pill looks like this:

```
APP_ROOT='/srv/fsg_distro'
RAILS_ROOT='/srv/fsg_distro/current'
RAILS_ENV='production'
RUBY_EXEC='/usr/bin/ruby'

Bluepill.application("fsg_distro", :log_file => "/srv/fsg_distro/shared/log/bluepill.log") do |app|
  app.process("delayed_job") do |process|
    process.working_dir = RAILS_ROOT

    process.start_grace_time    = 30.seconds
    process.stop_grace_time     = 30.seconds
    process.restart_grace_time  = 30.seconds

    process.start_command = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV} #{RUBY_EXEC} #{RAILS_ROOT}/script/delayed_job start"
    process.stop_command  = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV} #{RUBY_EXEC} #{RAILS_ROOT}/script/delayed_job stop"

    process.pid_file = "#{APP_ROOT}/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid"
    process.uid = "deploy"
    process.gid = "deploy"
  end
end
```

And my delayed job script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Comment: 2 questions seeing as how this is still unanswered. What permission would you need to write to the folder /srv/fsg_distro/shared/pids/ and does the user rails (from the machine george ?) have those permissions ?

Comment: Bluepill and me logged in are the same user.... As long as the user is the owner or in the group, he can write to the pids directory

Comment: @Tony Same issue here, did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you daemonize delayed_job (which you are) then you *must* generate a pid file for it yourself, or get delayed_job to do it for you, then bluepill expects to find the pid file once `grace_start_time` has passed.

If you run delayed_job in the foreground, and you tell bluepill to daemonize the process for you, then bluepill will generate the pid file.

You can't both monitor a self-daemonizing process and have bluepill create a pid file.  It's either one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I have no answer, but exactly the same question.
I have tried many, many solutions--including creating a startup script for init.d and calling that from bluepill as described in another monit-based posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226302/how-to-monitor-delayed-job-with-monit), but nothing has worked. Always there is a permissions issue with the PID file. How could this be the case when running as su?

I own the code, and share it with group www.
Do I need to create a custom user just to run bluepill? If so, with what settings?