# rvm monit delayed_job

Tags: rvm, delayed-job, monit

I am trying to run delayed_job using monit, but its failing to run as rvm's paths (local rvm installation per user basis) are not available to the command. My application is a rails2 app with bundler. Monit is not able to find bundler. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how i can tell about the rvm paths to monit?

I am getting the error

```
[rails@x-rws1 current]$ monit start delayed_job -c config/delayed_job.monitrc 
'delayed_job' start: /usr/bin/env
'delayed_job' failed to start
no such file to load -- bundler
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:3
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/boot.rb:123
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/environment.rb:12:in `require'
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/config/environment.rb:12
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/script/delayed_job:3:in `require'
/home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/script/delayed_job:3
```

My config/delayed_job.monitrc

```
set daemon  120

check process delayed_job with pidfile /home/rails/public_html/myapp/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=staging /home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/script/delayed_job start"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=staging /home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/script/delayed_job stop"
```

and script/delayed_job executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have properly working monit with other services and just need to add delayed_job daemon for rvm environment you can try to use this conf file (it works for me)

**/etc/monit/conf.d/delayed_job.conf** (i have ubuntu server)

```
check process delayed_job with pidfile /{project_folder}/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid
start program = "RAILS_ENV=production rvm -S /{project_folder}/script/delayed_job start"
stop program = "RAILS_ENV=production rvm -S /{project_folder}/script/delayed_job stop"
```

---

Here `rvm -S` command let script run under current rvm ruby environment

You can try to start daemon with

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rvm -S /{project_folder}/script/delayed_job start
```

command and if daemon will start (check it with changing last word to 'status') than you have good chances with delayed_job.conf file

And do not forget to check if pid file had created in `tmp/pids/` folder too

Answer (score 9):

'rvm -S' didn't work for me.

The instructions on http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-make-system-wide-rvm-installations-work-with-cron-monit-delayed_job-and-passenger-1021.html did.

```
check process delayed_job.0
  with pidfile /u/apps/adgrok/shared/pids/delayed_job.0.pid
  start program = "/usr/local/bin/rvm-shell -c 'RAILS_ENV=production /u/apps/adgrok/current/script/delayed_job start -i 0'" as uid deploy and gid deploy
  stop program = "/usr/local/bin/rvm-shell -c 'RAILS_ENV=production /u/apps/adgrok/current/script/delayed_job stop -i 0'" as uid deploy and gid deploy
  if 2 restarts within 15 cycles then timeout
```

There is also a noteworthy reference to a thread of discussion with the author of RVM about monit : http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/d1a6c1f6396a8bf6/51afece4c8943912?#51afece4c8943912

Comment: This works for me! Have tried many different solutions for several hours now.