# Run delayed jobs after deployed on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

With the delayed_jobs gem(https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in rails, I am able to queue my notifications. But I don't quite understand how can I run the queued jobs on the production server. I knew I can just run

```
$ rake jobs:work
```

in the console for the local server. As the documentation said,
You can then do the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Runs two workers in separate processes.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start

# Runs all available jobs and the exits
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start --exit-on-complete
# or to run in the foreground
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run --exit-on-complete
```

My question is how to integrate it with my Rails app?I was thinking to create a file called delayed_jobs.rb in config/initializers as:

```
# in config/initializers/delayed_jobs
script/delayed_job start if Rails.env.production?
```

But I am not sure if it is the right way to do with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workers run as separate processes, not as part of your Rails application. The simplest way would be to run the rake task in a [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session to prevent it from quitting when you log out of the terminal session. But there are better ways:

You would use a system such as monit or God or run the worker script provided by delayed_job. You'll find more information in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226302/how-to-monitor-delayed-job-with-monit).

Answer (score 0):

In my experiencie I've found my solution using [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) gem, which in words of the official doc

> It supports the scripting and execution of arbitrary tasks, and includes a set of sane-default deployment workflows.

Basically it is a tool that helps you to deploy your app, including all of those task like starting/stoping queues, migrating the database, bundle new gems, and all of those thing that we usually do with `ssh` connection.

[Here](http://www.ygamretuta.info/deploy-rails-4-2-with-capistrano-3-webfaction-figaro/) is a beutifull tutorial about capistrano and `webfaction` as hosting. And [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Delayed-Job-tasks-for-Capistrano-3) is a nice module to blend capistrano and `delayed_job`. At the end you should only be concern about the development environment, because every time that you need to deploy to production, you'll do a commit to your repository and then

```
$ cap production deploy
```

Which will manage the whole production environment, stoping/restarting those queues, restarting the app, installing gems and everything that you can perform through the capistrano scripting way.