# Keep Track of laravel websocket with monit centos

Tags: laravel, bash, monit, laravel-websockets

Im trying to monitor laravel-websocket with monit instead of supervisord because of more options it provides
So In my /home/rabter/laravelwebsocket.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
        start)
                echo $$ > /var/run/laravelwebsocket.pid;
                exec 2>&1 php /home/rabter/core/artisan websockets:serve  1>/tmp/laravelwebsocket.out
                ;;
        stop)  
                kill `cat /var/run/laravelwebsocket.pid` ;;
        *)  
                echo "usage: laravelwebsocket.sh {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

And in etc/monit.d I made a file named cwp.laravelwebsocket with code

```
check process laravelwebsocket with pidfile /var/run/laravelwebsocket.pid
start program "/bin/bash -c  /home/rabter/laravelwebsocket.sh start"
stop program "/bin/bash -c  /home/rabter/laravelwebsocket.sh stop"
if failed port 6001 then restart
if 4 restarts within 8 cycles then timeout
```

unfortunately with I run monit everything starts to get monitord but laravel websocket, and it does not   start once and in monit table infront I see 
`Process - laravelwebsocket   Execution failed | Does not exist`
How can I make monit monitor and start laravel-websocket on startup and on fails or errors or crashes?

I have looked into [Monitor a Laravel Queue Worker with Monit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971787/monitor-a-laravel-queue-worker-with-monit)
but no luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your bash script inserts its own pid into your pid file. Additionally, the php process should be send to background if using monit, because monit is a monitoring tool, rather then a supervisor.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $1 in
    start)
        php /home/rabter/core/artisan websockets:serve & 2>&1 >/tmp/laravelwebsocket.out
        echo $! > /var/run/laravelwebsocket.pid;
        ;;
    stop)
        kill $(cat /var/run/laravelwebsocket.pid) ;;
    *)
        echo "usage: $(basename $0) {start|stop}" ;;
    esac
exit 0
```

Then make that file executable with `chmod +x FILEPATH`.

This should now work:

```
check process laravelwebsocket with pidfile /var/run/laravelwebsocket.pid
    start program "/home/rabter/laravelwebsocket.sh start"
    stop program "/home/rabter/laravelwebsocket.sh stop"

    if failed port 6001 then restart
    if 4 restarts within 8 cycles then timeout
```

---

Do you use monit as init-system for a container? If so, please let me know. Then a few more details apply.

Comment: unfortunately in monit under status I still see `Execution failed | Does not exist` After replacing your scripts with mine and what do you mean by using monit as init-system ?

Comment: `Does not exist` points to two possible problems: (1) The file does not exist, (2) The file is not executable. Could you `ls -l /home/rabter/laravelwebsocket.sh` to ensure the file is present? The line should start with `-rwx`.

Regarding init-system: You can run monit inside a container as main service. If you just use monit in addition to an init-service (like initd, systemd, etc.) there's not problem here... ;)

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         342 Mar  6 10:51 laravelwebsocket.sh this is the response of the command and yes I do use it with systemd.