# no rules to make target 'micaz'

Tags: tinyos

I am a new in Tinyos.

I am following the tinyos Tutorial lesson 3: Mote-mote radio communication.

When I use 'make' to compile the program BlinkToRadio in lesson 3, I got a error message:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'micaz'.  Stop.`

But when I compile the program Blink, it works. So I dont think its the problem in enviorement variables.

Can anyone help me what it the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

this is a problem in the file Makefile, in the next code:

```
COMPONENT=BlinkToRadioAppC

include $(MAKERULES)
```

sometimes there is a space after $, or some other error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined `MAKERULES`?

You can check the definition of `MAKERULES` this way:

```
echo $MAKERULES
```

If not defined, you can define `MAKERULES` this way:

```
export MAKERULES=/opt/tinyos-2.1.0/support/make/MAKERULES
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using sudo when you're trying to build the app?  sudo will likely reset all your environment variable while you're using sudo.  You can set env_keep in the /etc/sudoers file to keep your $MAKERULES

```
Defaults env_keep += "MAKERULES"
```

or you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

Of course, it could be something entirely different....

Have you defined a Makefile? The Makefile for lesson 3 should be:

```
COMPONENT=BlinkToRadioAppC
include $(MAKERULES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors. There are 2 ways to solve it..... Do not run the code as root. This works for sure. 
2nd I am not so sure but if at all you want to run as root, try sudo bash and not other commands. 
Hope this helps