# RubyGems installation errors both when using 'sudo' and not using sudo

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I have a machine that is running Ubuntu Hardy, which provides its own RubyGems package.  Unfortunately that version of RubyGems (1.1.1) is too old to do anything useful with, so I decided to manually update RubyGems to the current version (1.3.6).  That part went smoothly, and if I do `gem -v`, I get `1.3.6` which is expected.  The problem is when I try to do: `sudo gem install rack`, it returns this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /home/username/.gem
```

Usually when I install gems as root, it knows to install it into `/usr/lib/ruby/gems`, so why is it checking my home directory at all?  Another quirk is when I do `gem install rack` (not as root), it says:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

which is where I want it to go.  I've already tried clearing source_caches, trying different versions of RubyGems (1.3.5), forcing installation into `/usr/lib` with `-i` to no avail.  Any ideas on why RubyGems is so insistent on checking my `/home` directory when installing as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a path issue coupled with having multiple versions installed.

Any difference in output between:

```
sudo gem env
```

and

```
gem env
```

Comment: No difference in the two, though in the GEM PATHS section: `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8` and `/home/username/.gem/ruby/1.8`. Shouldn't that not be there by default with sudo?

Comment: They're the same on my system, but only after I went through and 'scrubbed' everything after recompiling 1.9.  Things I checked:

1. Deleted the un-used gem command (had one in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin
2. Checked my ~/.gemrc file and cleaned the path up to point to my gem path in /usr/local/lib.  Used my ~/.gem folder as a backup
3. Matched my GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH environment variables up (in .profile/.bash_profile/.bashrc) with the .gemrc file
4. Checked permissions on the gem folders
5. You might also check to see if you have anything in /etc/gemrc

Comment: So I went through these suggestions and they all seem to check out: 1) only one gem executable in /usr/bin, 2) no .gemrc, 3) I never set these variables in my .profile, 4) gem folders had permissions for root, which sudo should be fine with, 5) no /etc/gemrc.  The only other hitch is maybe the fact that my home directory lives on AFS screws things up?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Maybe the old version of gem wasn't installed in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, and sudo is picking up a different PATH variable (to gem) or a GEM_PATH (which points to your /home/username path) from somewhere?

You might check /etc/environment as well and try to find out where sudo is picking up its environment variables from (maybe a root .profile?).

Comment: I believe the problem was caused by having my home directory on AFS.  RubyGems seems to write metadata into your `.gem` directory (`~/.gem/specs`) regardless of whether you are running as root via sudo.  But running as root means that you credentials don't carry over and you can't do anything to AFS.  I ended up using `sudo su` and installing things as root proper.  It did install into `/usr/lib/ruby/gems` and wrote some metadata into `~/.gem/specs`.  Thanks for all the help, I was able to narrow down the scope of the problem a lot.

Comment: My output for these is exactly the same. How else can I figure out, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
gem environment
```

and checking the values for the GEM PATH. More info at http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page31

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem myself on Fedora 15, so I ran 'gem install' with the '--backtrace' option to see what was going on.

It turned out it was failing at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:203 where it tried to chdir to the directory it had previously stored (the home directory of the user I was running sudo as)

I didn't extensively debug to see what the underlying cause was, just rather used a quick workaround so I could continue moving forward. The workaround was simply to cd to the root directory, eg **cd /**, before running the gem install command.

Hope this helps / solves your issue.

Answer (score -3):

Woulda been easier to su (password) then chmod 755 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Comment: It's safer to install gems in your homedir or /usr/local/.... Don't mess with system installed files and don't make library folders writable to every user. It will backfire.