# Cannot use RVM-installed Ruby with sudo

Tags: ruby, rvm, sudo

I have succefully configured RVM to use Ruby 1.9.2 and everything is fine. However when I'm trying to run Ruby using `sudo` it says it cannot find RVM or Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]

$ sudo ruby -v
[sudo] password for administrator:
sudo: ruby: command not found
```

Is that correct behavior or is my RVM misconfigured? Perhaps I should be using the [system wide install](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/)?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use `rvmsudo` command instead of `sudo`

Comment: +1 - Thanks calas! This worked awesomely for me. I have many gems that require me to use sudo when running them (such as RubyCAS) and this solved my problem eloquently. Thanks again!

Comment: I needed to update rvm to install the command. `rvm update --head` fixed the problem for me, this was just after a fresh install.

Comment: Glad I found this.  I was pulling out hair.

Comment: @tgandrews It's `rvm get [stable|latest|etc]` nowadays :)

Answer (score 6):

Taking @calas' answer one step further, add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias sudo=rvmsudo
```

This avoids the requirement of having to remember to change `sudo` to `rvmsudo` for every command (particularly annoying for copy/pasted commands).

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is resetting your PATH.  rvm works by modifying your PATH environment variable so that the ruby you're using is a particular one, probably in your ~/.rvm/rubies directory.  When you ruby ruby with sudo, sudo is not using that modified PATH, and so it will not find your rvm ruby.  See this question for workarounds: [sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

Answer (score 0):

@calas's answer is the answer. but If you can't achieve your goal by using `rvmsudo`, e.g. install the nginx using the command `passenger-install-nginx-module`, please just change the owner of the related folder/path. e.g.

```
$ chown <your_username>:<your_group> /opt -R
$ passenger-install-nginx-module
```