# RVM is not a function even when running command as login shell

Tags: ruby, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use RVM-installed Ruby with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644897/cannot-use-rvm-installed-ruby-with-sudo)

I'm running into the same "RVM is not a function..." error when executing the command `sudo rvm use 1.9.3` as everyone else, but try as I might, I cannot seem to resolve it.  I've read and followed through with all of the common troubleshooting tips, but nothing seems to work...

My System --- OS: Ubuntu 12.10 --- Ruby Version: 1.9.3 --- RVM Version: 1.18.3

I have done the following to try to repair the issue:

1. Checked the 'Run command as login shell' option in the "Title and Command" tab for Terminal preferences
2. Added the following code block to ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, and ~/.zprofile
   `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

   `if test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; then`
       `[ "$(type -t rvm)" = "function" ] || source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
   fi`
3. Running `user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and then `user$ type rvm | head -n 1` DOES return `rvm is a function`.  But then running `sudo rvm use 1.9.3` returns "RVM is not a function"

What else can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run rvm with `sudo`, sudo is running a new process which defeats the `function` approach which can change current running shell environment.

Comment: Right.  Looks like `sudo` was the problem here.  Not using sudo allows RVM to run.  I didn't know that sudo would be running a new process and defeat the `function` approach.

Thanks for the help!