# Preserve sudo environment

Tags: ssh, sudo

I'm trying to execute a script from a different server using ssh

Here's the command I'm using from server 1 to launch a query on server 2:

```
ssh -t user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx "cd /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/subdomains/preprod/; sudo ./replace.sh";
```

but the problem is that when I do `sudo` the `$home` = `/root` while the script is under: `/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/subdomains/preprod/`

How can i tell sudo to preserve the environment?

I tried `sudo -P -` , `sudo -H`, without any luck.

Comment: Does the replace.sh use the path from which it is executed? Otherwise you could just do sudo /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/subdomains/preprod/replace.sh.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this , it work that way .

But I'm more interested in knowing if there is an argument that we can pass to sudo to keep the current Path instead of setting it back to root ...

Answer (score 21):

That's what I got from the man page.

```
sudo -E
```

> -E The -E (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset
>   option in sudoers(5)).  It is only
>   available when either the matching
>   command has the SETENV tag or the
>   setenv option is set in sudoers(5).

Comment: Also tried that option yesterday and it failed :)

Comment: apparently modification of the PATH environment variable still can occur despite -E (esp. in Ubuntu, where this occurs by default) as a security concern.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: @Tarek The use of -E maybe restricted by your admin because environemtn variables could potentially cause harm. Though in that case sudo should come back with a clear statement saying: You are not allowed to use -E. If it just silently fails, you will have a different problem.