# Using rvmsudo with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am trying to setup capistrano to deploy my rails3 app easily. I'm pretty new to rails.

Everything is working as it should except that I am trying to restart the standalone passenger server.

I am running redmine on the same server, so I followed http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/ to get multiple versions of ruby/rails to run. This works fine until I try and get capistrano to restart the passenger server.

The problem is the 'sudo' doesn't pass environment settings through (as found on: [sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) )

Everything works if I can use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo', since rvmsudo passes along the correct environment information. But, if I use 'rvmsudo' in my Captistrano deployment, it hangs waiting for my sudo password.

I would like to implement a try_rvmsudo that works exactly like try_sudo does, where it sends the password if it is asked for. but I can't seem to find any information on doing this.

here is the restart command that I am trying to use:

```rb
desc "Restart Passenger server"
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run <<-CMD
      if [[ -f #{release_path}/tmp/pids/passenger.#{passenger_port}.pid ]];
      then
        cd #{deploy_to}/current && #{passenger_path}passenger stop -p #{passenger_port} --pid-file #{release_path}/tmp/pids/passenger.#{passenger_port}.pid;
      fi
    CMD
    # restart passenger standalone on the specified port/environment and as a daemon
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && rvmsudo #{passenger_path}passenger start -e #{rails_env} -p #{passenger_port} -a 127.0.0.1 -d --pid-file #{release_path}\
/tmp/pids/passenger.#{passenger_port}.pid"
  end
```

And it hangs saying:

```
 ** [out :: snapshotroulette.com] [sudo] password for deployer:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found out that I can have Capistrano send the sudo password first (by running a sudo command). Sudo remembers your password for a small time (5 minutes by default). And, rvmsudo simply calls sudo with some environment variables set, so it too remembers your password.

It's not really pretty, but it works:

```rb
desc "Restart Passenger server"
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    # Hack to have capistrano enter the sudo password (for rvmsudo later)
    sudo "whoami"
    run <<-CMD
      if [[ -f #{release_path}/tmp/pids/passenger.#{passenger_port}.pid ]];
      then
        cd #{deploy_to}/current && rvmsudo passenger stop;
      fi
    CMD

    # restart passenger standalone on the specified port/environment and as a daemon
    # The sleep 1 is to give the server enough time to spawn. The session was closing before it spawned, so it never actually spawned
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && rvmsudo passenger start -e #{rails_env} -p #{passenger_port} -a 127.0.0.1 -d --pid-file #{release_path}/tmp/pids/passeng\
er.#{passenger_port}.pid && sleep 1"
  end
```

Any other solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of rvmsudo hanging capistrano seems to have been fixed in more recent versions of rvm.  For my running 'rvm get stable' on the target machines fixed the problem.