# rvmsudo switch for Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

This is similar to:

[Using rvmsudo with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285306/using-rvmsudo-with-capistrano)

I'm wondering if there is a specific switch in rvm/capistrano that enables rvmsudo.  Without it I get errors like:

```
* executing "cd /home/Blog/releases/20110826194116 && bundle install --gemfile /home/Blog/releases/20110826194116/Gemfile --path /home/Blog/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["199.168.0.1"]
    [199.168.0.1] executing command
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] 
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] creating Makefile
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] 
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] make
*** [err :: 199.168.0.1] sh: make: Permission denied
```

Comment: Since this was somewhat time critical, I went ahead and added an 'after deploy:update_code' filter that handles bundle update in rvmsudo.  I also asked this on the RVM mailing list, no reply yet http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/cb85821e060dfe3d#

Comment: Any particular reason why you're actually installing gems at the rvm level on deployment?  I would suggest doing bundle install --deployment instead; it'll unroll an "installed copy" within the code tree for the code to use.

Comment: Good point Nick, ill look into that

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the rvm envrionment variables like this as part of your deploy:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@some_gemset'
set :rvm_type, :user
```

then RVM commands will be scoped to this gemset and user.

Comment: Clearly this isn't a concern for systems where rvm is installed for a user. You need rvmsudo for system installs.