# Capistrano rvmsudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano, sudo

Capistrano does not work with `rvmsudo` in my deploy.rb.

I tried

```
set :sudo, 'rvmsudo'
set :sudo_prompt, 'password: '
```

And then running commands with:

```
sudo "god -c config/unicorn.god --log-level debug"
```

But Capistrano gets stuck on the password prompt.

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285306/using-rvmsudo-with-capistrano) says to use `sudo "whoami"` and then `rvmsudo` because it will remember your password for 5 minutes, but my password is not remembered.

**context:**

```
desc "Start unicorn"
  task :start, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  sudo "god -c config/unicorn.god --log-level debug"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you doing

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

?

Its hacky, but you could try:

```
after "deploy:update_code", :do_bundle_install

task :do_bundle_install do
  run "cd #{current_release} && rvmsudo bundle install --gemfile #{current_release}/Gemfile --path {path to install}/bundle --without development test cucumber"
end
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing `require bundler/capistrano`

Comment: And I wouldn't be able to do what you suggested because of the context I am using this in (updated post)

Comment: does this actually work for anyone? rvmsudo doesnt work for me even in a triggered task

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
task :do_something do
    run "cd #{latest_release} && rvmsudo -p '#{sudo_prompt}' some_command"
end
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try using sudo inside the run command, but calling the sudo from the set:

```
task :do_something do
  run "#{sudo} root task"
end
```

This way if you change your mind, you dont need to rewrite all tasks, only remove the `set :sudo`.