# "gem install" requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7, which is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
$ gem -v
1.8.5
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02

$ sudo gem install sanitize
ERROR:  Error installing sanitize:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7
```

This happens for other gems as well, not just nokogiri. I am on Ruby 1.8.7 and have set my $PATH to include `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby` before `/usr/bin` where system Ruby (1.8.6) is installed.

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin

$ which ruby
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
$which gem
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sudo command is most probably changing your PATH variable. Try `sudo gem env` and you can verify this. As a solution you might try this:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH gem install ...
```

Also see here for further discussion:
[sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

As a workaround you could also do:

```
sudo su -m
```

To get to a root prompt using the `-m` modifier to *preserve environment*. Then from that root prompt do your gem installs.

Answer (score 0):

Well your `sudo` command looks fine (i.e., no dash there so it should be reusing your environment), but you could try `sudo which gem` just to be sure. It sometimes depends on the version of Unix/Linux.

I tracked something like this down once upon a time.  My path (and yours) was correct, but there was something internal to gem that either ignored the path or was looking for "standard" directories *first* and thus finding the older version of ruby.

My solution was to uninstall the old version. Not the most elegant but I didn't need the old version anyway.

Good luck, I hope you're in a position to uninstall the old version.