# Capistrano: Can I set an environment variable for the whole cap session?

Tags: environment-variables, capistrano

I've got a staging server with both standard Ruby and Ruby Enterprise installed.  As standard Ruby refuses to install a critical gem, I need to set $PATH so that ruby/gem/rake/etc. always refer to the REE versions.  And since I use Capistrano to deploy to our machines, I need to do it in Capistrano.

**How can I set an environment variable once, and have it persist throughout the Capistrano session?**

1) It's easy to do in bashrc files, but Capistrano doesn't read bashrc files.

2) I'd use Capistrano's

```
default_environment['PATH'] = 'Whatever'
```

but Capistrano uses these environment variables like

```
env PATH=Whatever command arg ...
```

and they're lost whenever another shell is spun up within the executable passed to env.  Like when you use sudo.  Which is kinda important:

```
[holt@Michaela trunk]$ env VAR=hello ruby -e "puts ENV['VAR']"
hello
[holt@Michaela trunk]$ env VAR=hello sudo ruby -e "puts ENV['VAR']"
nil
```

3) And I can't use the bash export command, as these are lost too - Capistrano seems to start up a new shell for each command (or something like that), and that's lost, too:

```
cap> export MYVAR=12
[establishing connection(s) to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
cap> echo $MYVAR
 ** [out :: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 
cap>
```

4) I've tried messing with Capistrano's :shell and :pty options as well (and in combination with the other approaches), but no luck there, either.

**So - what's the right way to do this?**  This seems like such a basic task that there should be a really simple way to accomplish it, but I'm out of ideas.  Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 57):

I have the exactly same problem, but I think this solution is better:

```
set :default_environment, { 
  'env_var1' => 'value1',
  'env_var2' => 'value2'
}
```

This works for me like a charm.

Comment: hmmm, not working for me see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889642/capistrano-environment-variable?lq=1

Comment: In Capistrano 3 it's `set :default_env, { ... }`

Comment: Stupid question, but I'm trying the same thing and it's not working. Anyway to debug it?

Comment: How could puts these in a .env file?

Answer (score 10):

If you need to set a variable on the remote host other than PATH, you should know that sshd only allows certain `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` environment variables by default, for security reasons. As Lou said, you can either do `cap shell` and use the `cap> printenv` command, or you can do `cap COMMAND=printenv invoke` in one command.

If you see the variable when you ssh into the remote shell normally, but you don't see it in the cap `printenv` command, here's one solution:

1. Set `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in your remote server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and restart sshd
2. Edit the `~/.ssh/environment` file for the remote user you are ssh'ing in as, and put your variable(s) there as `VARIABLE=value`

Now those should show up when you do `cap COMMAND=printenv invoke`

Comment: This might work, but it requires root-privilege settings change.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have in fact 2 problems:

1) **You want to change the PATH on your remote host(s).**

Alter/set the path in your .bashrc on your remote host(s) and run `cap> printenv`, if your path is right, goto #2, else try to add `export BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc` to your `/etc/profile` (be careful, ~/.bashrc will then be run for all non-interactive shell for all users)

2) **You want sudo to keep your PATH**

Run `visudo` on your remote host(s) and add:

```
Defaults        exempt_group = "<your_user>"
```

Comment: Good call - I wasn't aware that sudo obscured the local environment.  Looks like just adding the -E option fixes most cases, but $PATH is special ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)).  I'll play around with this a bit more and get back to you.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I needed to set an environment variable for a specific task to work. The "run" command allows you to pass options which include :env:

```
run "cmd", :env => { 'name' => 'value' }
```

In my case, I wanted to add the environment variable to a task that I didn't write, so I used default_run_options which is used by all invocations of run. I added this to the top of my Capfile:

```
default_run_options[:env] = { 'name' => 'value' }
```

Comment: I've seen this solution elsewhere, but I can't get it to work for me - I get a `NameError: undefined local variable or method `default_run_options' for main:Object` error. I put that assignment statement at the top of my `Capfile`, before the first `namespace :deploy do` block. What could I be doing differently?

Comment: How are you running the task? If you run cap task, it should define default_run_options during the load process so it would be available by the time it gets to your Capfile. Even with a one-line Capfile that just says default_run_options[:x] = { 'y' => 'z' }, I can run cap shell.

Answer (score 0):

I tried unsuccessfully to use @brian-deterling's technique, which is pretty commonly used by others who have discussed this... Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but meanwhile I found the `dotenv-rails` gem, and it worked very nicely for loading up values out of a `.env` file in my project root.

The instructions on their [Github repo](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) are pretty straight-forward. I added the `Dotenv.load` to my `config/application.rb`