# Capistrano starting Sunspot does not find Java

Tags: java, ssh, capistrano, sunspot

I am using Sunspot Solr and I am writing a Capistrano task to start/stop it.

```
  namespace :sunspot do
    task :start, :roles => :app do
      run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start"
    end
  end
```

However when I run this task, I get error of not finding Java:

```
*** [err :: example.com] /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/solr/java.rb:5:in ``': No such file or directory - java -version (Errno::ENOENT)
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/solr/java.rb:5:in `installed?'
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:200:in `ensure_java_installed'
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:27:in `initialize'
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/bin/sunspot-solr:16:in `new'
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/bin/sunspot-solr:16:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/sunspot-solr:23:in `load'
*** [err :: example.com] from /home/user/deploy/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/sunspot-solr:23:in `<main>'
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3@project' -c 'cd /home/user/deploy/project/current && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start'" on example.com
```

Sunspot's Java checking code is [here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_solr/lib/sunspot/solr/java.rb).

If I manually run `cd /home/user/deploy/project/current && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start` on the server it works as expected. I don't know why Java is not present if the command is called through Capistrano.

Comment: Do you run command manually and via capistrano as same user?

Comment: Did you check if #{rails_env} is correct. 'staging' ?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Yes the same user (sorry for late reply)

Comment: @Nishant yes it is correct as staging/production

Comment: Do you know where path to java is specified? I usually add it to `.bashrc`. I don't know if capistrano read `.bashrc` and load `PATH` from it. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session) question: you may need to specify path to java in some more specific place.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Thanks. I found out it is not in path. But my .bashrc did not declare java path either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my server, Java paths are loaded inside the `/etc/profile' script.

However Capistrano does not load that script.

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/capistrano/Xo6CZW-381o), setting this in the Capistrano deploy.rb file will make sure its shell loads the profile script, which in term sets Java path for me.

`default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash --login'`