# Changing Ruby version during deploy

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano, bundler

I have a box with 3 Rails apps on it. I wan't to upgrade one of the apps so that it uses Ruby 2.0.0, while leaving the others running on 1.9.3-p394. I have both those Rubies installed via Rvm.

I'm trying to control the Ruby version that each app uses via it's Gemfile.

```
# Gemfile
ruby '2.0.0'
```

So, I changed the version number in the Gemfile locally, made sure it all worked, committed and now I'm trying to deploy the change to the server.

However, the `cap deploy` fails at this point

```
bundle install --gemfile [path to release Gemfile] --path [path to app bundle] --deployment --quiet --without development test
```

because

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

This is correct technically, my Gemfile does specify 2.0.0 and the app is currently running on 1.9.3. I'm trying to make it change versions before bundling though. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PATH is not set up correctly.  You probably don't have bin: as the first entry in your path.  That would lead to this error.

Even if you're not using Heroku it's worth reading this page on troubleshooting that issue: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Here is a link to an answer which will explain how to change your PATH on the server: [Capistrano: Can I set an environment variable for the whole cap session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session)

Comment: Which `bin` do I want in the path? The one in the Rails root right? I've added `set :default_environment, { 'PATH' => "[path to rails root]/bin:$PATH" }` to my deploy config and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: first element in PATH should be just "bin:" according to the articles I found googling for an answer to this - see the heroku article

Comment: as a separate strategy have you looked at https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/ already?

Comment: Yeah, tried naked `bin` too. Doesn't work. There's definitely a few steps on the `rvm-capistrano` Gihub readme that I haven't done. Will try them now.

Comment: Yeah - I am still learning managing this stuff all together myself so I'm trying to track this one down for the old memorybanks in case I run into it later so I'll add anything I find to this comment thread or update the answer if I find a definitive one.

Comment: Ok, kinda silly but I had `set :rvm_ruby_string, :default` in my deploy config which obviously was forcing Rvm to use `1.9.3` when deploying. The issue still isn't really solved though since I can't see a good way to tell it to use whatever is in the Gemfile.

Comment: Well I hate to suggest it - and you're probably doing it anyway - but now go through the previous steps again and it may now work :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have rvm maybe you can try to do

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

before your bundler call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rvm set the default to ruby 2.0.0 on your server

```
rvm --default use 2.0.0
```

Resolved the problem for me deploying to an AWS server from my mac - but I guess if I need to update my older sites I'll have to set the default back to 1.9.3 before deploying.