# Capistrano environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I saw this [Capistrano: Can I set an environment variable for the whole cap session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session)

And I am using this to set my variable

```
  set :default_environment, self[:default_environment].
    merge('PAYPAL_SANDBOX' => 'true')
```

I print `self[:default_environment]` and I get `PAYPAL_SANDBOX` correctly set

However, how could I test if rails server is running with that variable set?, I think is not working, because in another part I have

```
ENV['PAYPAL_SANDBOX'] ? 'development' : Rails.env
```

and I am getting into second part of this sentence, I mean is taking `Rails.env` instead of `development`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this:

1. I created a file inside my server, just to mark it

   ```
   touch test_server
   ```
2. Inside an initializer

   ```
   TEST_SERVER = `ls ~/test_server`.present?
   ```
3. Then,

   ```
   TEST_SERVER ? 'development' : Rails.env
   ```

Comment: Won't work in my use case, but I think it would work in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was like this:

1. Set global variable

   `set :my_number, 23`
2. Get global variable

   `puts "My number is #{fetch(:my_number)}"`