# Capistrano and environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, capistrano, capistrano3

I've switched to using [environment variables for configuration](http://12factor.net/config) and it works very well - except when I have to deploy or run tasks with capistrano.

Capistrano 3 seems to execute each command prefixed with `/usr/bin/env` which erases any environment variables I've set through `.bashrc`.

*EDIT* - on doing some more reasearch, this might not be the issue, the issue might be because capistrano executes as a non-login, non-interactive shell and does not load `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Still stuck, though.

What would be the best way of making sure the environment vars are set when capistrano executes its tasks?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You might be best looking at the [difference between `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` and `SHELL VARIABLES`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference)

When you fire SSH, your app will load the SHELL variables which are defined in your `.bashrc` file. These only exist for the life of the shell, and therefore, we don't use them as much as `ENV` vars

You may be better putting the `ENV` vars in:

```
/etc/environment
```

Like this:

```
export ENVIRONMENT_VAR=value
```

This will make the variables available throughout the system, not just in different shell sessions

---

**Update**

Have you tried

[Capistrano: Can I set an environment variable for the whole cap session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session)

```
set :default_env, { 
  'env_var1' => 'value1',
  'env_var2' => 'value2'
}
```

Comment: I need the variables to be set for a single user, but available to processes run. I've got `export FOO=BAR` in .bashrc and this works fine in SSH. Just not in Capistrano.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm - let me have a look! Thanks for reply

Comment: default_environment seems to have no effect, strangely enough. I'm running a test task that echoes a test env variable and `BASH_VERSION`. `BASH_VERSION` is shown, the test variable is blank

Comment: Is the env var in your `/etc/environment` or `.bashrc`?

Comment: In `.bashrc`. I need these env vars to be applied only for a one user.

Comment: Sorry, I was just checking :) So it loads the bash_version? Did you set that specifically though?

Comment: No, I didn't set that. I was just using that as a control test.

Comment: Okay - `bash_version` will likely be an ENV var set in the system. You're trying to load `SHELL` vars

Comment: Ah, it seems capistrano3 uses `default_env`, not `default_environment` (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/564). And that seems to  work. Less than ideal, but it'll work for me :)

Comment: NICE - so this sets SHELL vars when you deploy? Capistrano the most ridiculous software I've used for non-documentation

Comment: Hahah, indeed. And yes, it prefixes each command with `VAR=VAL FOO=BAR ...`

Comment: how could I puts these in a .env file?

Comment: I think we don't add `export` in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @RichardPeck putting the env var in `/etc/environment` did not work for capistrano deploy user, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 62):

Although this has been answered, I'm going to leave this here in case anyone else is in the same situation I was.

Capistrano *does* load `.bashrc`.  But if you'll notice at the top of the file there is this:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

The solution was simply to put any setup above this and Capistrano works how I want.

This solution was also noted at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/413).

Comment: Works like a charm, less complicated than the above solutions.

Comment: This helped me with a Rails 4.2 app and Capistrano3. Rails was looking for things like the database password and secret_key_base to be set by ENV variables ... which I had added to the end of my `bashrc` file ... but those weren't bound so everything was crashing towards the end of the deploy.

Comment: This helped me after spending hours trying to find the right solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! I have moved all my customer config to the top of .bashrc file.

Answer (score 31):

In order to debug the issue update `config/deploy.rb` with a simple task:

```
namespace :debug do
  desc 'Print ENV variables'
  task :env do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :printenv
    end
  end
end
```

now run `cap staging debug:env`. You should be able to see effective configuration of `ENV` variables.

The order and names of files are dependent on your distribution, e.g. on Ubuntu the sourcing sequence is following:

1. `/etc/environment`
2. `/etc/default/locale`
3. `/etc/bash.bashrc`
4. `~/.bashrc`

When `~/.bashrc` contains first lines like this, any code afterwards won't be sourced:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

To understand how `capistrano` loads ENV variables this chart ([source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1884#issuecomment-336092876)) might be helpful.

Most likely the `~/.bash*` file is not loaded due to non-interactive session.

[image: capistrano env variables loading]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set environment variables in the `/etc/environment` file to make them available to all users and process within a system. Environment variables in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files are only available within a shell session and not for automatically spawned processes and services.

I made a Capistrano library ([`capistrano-env_config`](https://github.com/itay-grudev/capistrano-env_config)) some time ago for managing and syncing environment variables across a cluster which works exactly by modifying the `/etc/environment` file. It's easy to use and is similar to how you can set environment variables with the Heroku toolbelt. Here are some examples:

```
cap env:list
cap env:get[VARIABLE_NAME, VARIABLE_NAME, ...] 
cap env:unset[VARIABLE_NAME, VARIABLE_NAME, ...] 
cap env:set[VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE, VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE, ...] 
cap env:sync
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on was:

1. Enable the PermitUserEnvironment option in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config of all servers I need to deploy to.
2. Add a ~/.ssh/environment file for each user's home dir I deploy to with env vars in the form of KEY=VALUE pairs (I deploy every app and service via it's own user to that user's home dir).

Reference:  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files#.7E.2F.ssh.2Fenvironment

It's actually worse than that.  I use Upstart to manage Puma/Rails, and need the env vars set there as well.  So, after days of experimentation, I ended up on the following complete but horrific solution:

1. Set my env vars in the user's .bashrc using "export KEY=VALUE".  (So they exist when I SSH in interactively.)
2. Set my env vars in the user's .ssh/environment file using "KEY=VALUE".  (So they exist when Capistrano SSHs in.)
3. Set my env vars in /etc/init/puma.conf's "script" section.  (So they exist when Puma/Rails starts.)

It's a pain in the ass maintaining the same list of env vars in multiple files/templates and in multiple formats (with export, without export...).  Luckily it's made slightly easier/more reliable by using Puppet to manage the configuration of the node before Capistrano is used to deploy to it...

I really hate the entire domain of linux shells, initialization, and dotfiles.  It's time for a complete reboot.

Comment: "just use ENV variables" they say!! What a pain to put them in 3 places! If the sole reason for it is to prevent putting secrets in source control files, why not just add them to a config file that is not in source control?

Comment: I've since abandoned everything I previously built for that project and started over with entirely new and better tech: Docker, Thin, Sinatra, Sequel, and etcd.  Working on a tool right now to store/retrieve production secrets to/from etcd.  No more Rails, Puppet, Capistrano, SSH, env vars, and all that other clunky garbage.  I'm not even done, and already the difference has been like night and day.

Comment: 3. Set my env vars in /etc/init/puma.conf's "script" section. (So they exist when Puma/Rails starts.) - This did the trick for me! Thanks a ton!