# Postgresql authentication from Capistrano fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy a Rails application with Capistrano. I got Capistrano more or less configured. I know it works since I already deployed another app which used SQLite as database.
Now, the current one uses Postgresql and I can't figure out why Capistrano doesn't get through authentication.
The error which shows up when capstrano tries to `exec bundle exec rake db:migrate` is the following:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user 'nameofrailsapplication'
```

Currently I'm trying this configuration on the server:

**/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf**

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I fiddled around with `md5` and `trust` but instead of the `ConnectionBad` error I'm getting a password error. Since I don' want Capistrano to interactively ask for a password at this point, `md5` didn't get me very far.

My local config:

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/postgresql'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

The `capistrano/postgresql` gem seems to do it's job well, within the deploy messages I can see that it does indeed take the database name and creates a password which gets passed on to the server.
To be safe I configured the database name inside deploy.rb:

from **config/deploy.rb**:

```
 # config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, "nameofrailsapplication"
set :pg_database, "nameofrailsapplication"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:gituser/repo-name.git"

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :deploy_user, "deployers"

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

I suspect that the fact that the deploy_user is different then the postgresql user (same as database name) might cause some trouble here. The system user `deployers` does not exist in the database, nor does the database user on the system.

**config/database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: nameofrailsapplication_development
test:
  <<: *default
  #database: nameofrailsapplication_test
  database: nameofrailsapplication_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database:nameofrailsapplication
  username: nameofrailsapplication
  password: <%= ENV['NAME-OF-RAILS-APPLICATION_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Last thing I should probably mention is that I am also using the figaro gem, which copies the database.yml over to the server. For this purpose 
I run the following capistrano task:

```
namespace :figaro do
  desc "SCP transfer figaro configuration to the shared folder"
  task :setup do
    on roles(:app) do
      upload! "config/application.yml","#{shared_path}/application.yml", via: :scp
    end
  end

  desc "Symlink application.yml to the release path"
  task :symlink do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "ln -sf #{shared_path}/application.yml #{current_path}/config/application.yml"
    end
  end
end
after "deploy:started", "figaro:setup"
after "deploy:symlink:release", "figaro:symlink"
```

Any suggestion greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1:** I set up ssh keys correctly on git and the server.

**Edit 2:** I can log into the DB as 'nameofrailsapplication' locally from the without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself finally, actually really simple. I kind of took for granted that the capistrano/postgresql plugin was in charge of managing the whole create-user-and-login business, so it didn't cross my mind that I should probably take care of things on the server side myself.

Anyway, what I did was peeking into the database file on the server (which was created by capistrano), retrieving the capistrano-generated password and finally logging into the postgres user to change the railsuser password to the one in the file. Solved.

Comment: shouldn't the capistrano postgresql gem do this for you?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is really simple. The environment variable you are using in your `database.yml` configuration is not available for capistrano. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672631/capistrano-and-environment-variables).

Capistrano executes remote commands via [SSHKit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit). In the documentation of SSHKit it's mention that:

> It's often a problem that programmatic SSH sessions don't have the same environment variables as interactive sessions.

You have different options to set the environment to the login shell SSHKit uses:

1. Add your environment variables to `/etc/environment`. Please consider, that this variable is accessible to all everyone on the remote system. Maybe it's not a save place to store passwords.
2. Set the variables in `~/.ssh/environment` and activate `PermitUserEnvironment` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The variables are only visible to a specific user, but they aren't to the rails application.
3. Use the functionality of shared and linked files of Capistrano. Create a `database.yml` and `secrets.yml` in `public/config/`. I think this is the simplest and safest option.