# How can I instruct Capistrano 3 to load my shell environment variables set at remote host?

Tags: ruby, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I want to instruct Capistrano to load environment variables that are defined on remote server. How can I do that?

It seems that when I export my environment variables inside `.bashrc` file, they are not taken into account by Capistrano. Capistrano seems to be executing a `/usr/bin/env` to create the environment for executing remote commands, but this does not seem to be loading the environment variables from `.bashrc`.

Let me tell you also that I am using `rvm-capistrano` too (just in case it might help).

Any clue?

Answer (score 43):

Capistrano actually *does* load `.bashrc`.  But near the top of the file you will find one of the following lines:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

If you do any `export`ing after the above lines, it will not be reached by Capistrano. The solution was simply to move my setup above this line—and Capistrano works how I want.

This solution was also noted at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/413).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your current environment variables to a remote execution with ssh by issuing:

```
env | ssh user@host remote_program
```

Also taken the example from [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/ssh-kit/)

```
on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
  within "/opt/sites/example.com" do
    # commands in this block execute in the
    # directory: /opt/sites/example.com
    as :deploy  do
      # commands in this block execute as the "deploy" user.
      with rails_env: :production do
        # commands in this block execute with the environment
        # variable RAILS_ENV=production
        rake   "assets:precompile"
        runner "S3::Sync.notify"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

looks like you can use `with` set environment variables for your execution. So read your current environment variables and set them using `with` .

Comment: But this will use the environment variables on the client machine, the one I am running deploy from. Not the environment variables defined on the remote machine, the one I am deploying to. My questions says: "...to load environment variables that are defined on remote server..."

Answer (score -1):

Capistrano doesn't load `.bashrc` since it's not interactive shell. As far as I remember though it does load `.bash_profile` though so you will probably have better luck using that.

Comment: I just tried on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1, and .bash_profile was not loaded during a Capistrano-initiated SSH command execution (neither was .profile and .bashrc).  Also tried by manually running SSH from command line.

Comment: For me it reads `.bashrc` and does not read `.bash_profile`. I'm using CentOS.

Comment: Wrong, loads .bashrc on Debian too.

Answer (score -1):

In Capistrano 3 it's `set :default_env, { ... }`

Like here:

```
set :default_environment, { 
  'env_var1' => 'value1',
  'env_var2' => 'value2'
}
```

You can refer to this:
[Previous post..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session)

Comment: This solution does not answer my question. It loads some environment variables as defined in the hash given. So, it is going to define the environment variable 'env_var1' with value 'value1'. But this is not what I am asking. I want capistrano to run the shell scripts using the environment variables that are already defined in my system for the user that is used to ssh the remote host.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos Did you find a solution to this? I am struggling with the exact same issue.