# Devise omniauth facebook The parameter app_id is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to setup Devise with omniauth to allow facebook logins via my rails app.  I have read through several guides / SO questions and they point that I don't have the `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` setup in an environment variable on the box which is running the rails app.  Well I setup an environment variable on the production box from which the app is running under that particular user.  I added the `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and the `FACEBOOK_SECRET` environment variables to the `.bashrc` and I put the app in development mode via the facebook apps page.  I also checked the `roles` section of the app via the developer apps portal on the facebook site, and my facebook account is set to `Administrator`, so I'm a little perplexed as to why this isn't working.  Currently I'm seeing something like this, [image]

Comment: Are you sure the variable is in the right .bashrc ? The one of the user that actually runs the instance of your rails server ?

Comment: Yes, I just doubled checked that, and puma is running under the user which deploys the app via capistrano, and I echoed `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and it prints the hash of characters.

Comment: I recall having that same problem with one capistrano deployment and ended up using figaro gem to keep track of my global variables... It's probably not the answer you're looking for but maybe another way for you to get it done :)

Comment: I recall that the capistrano instance that starts your server doesn't run bashrc when it logs in to your server since it doesn't run an interactive session. You can view a few solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479348/how-can-i-instruct-capistrano-3-to-load-my-shell-environment-variables-set-at-re

Comment: what does echo $FACEBOOK_APP_ID prints? in your terminal

Comment: you can use a nice gem call dotenv

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use environment variables, let's suppose that my appid is 121 and secret is abc.

Then my `omniauth.rb` will look like:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "121", "abc"
end
```