# Devise secret_key not set, even though it's present in profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capistrano, capistrano3

The first line of my ~/.profile file is:

```
export DEVISE_TOKEN_AUTH_SECRET_KEY="secrethere"
```

When I SSH in to my deployer account, echo $DEVISE_TOKEN_AUTH_SECRET_KEY prints the secret key normally. However, when running

```
cap production deploy
```

I get

```
Devise.secret_key was not set
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano makes its connection as a non-login, non-interactive shell. It will not automatically evaluate the various home scripts.

How Capistrano makes its connection is described here: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/ptys/

What files are evaluated on the various shell modes is described here: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization#bash

A number of other ways to set environment variables is shown here: [Capistrano: Can I set an environment variable for the whole cap session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session)

A duplicate question is here: https://superuser.com/questions/564926/profile-is-not-loaded-when-using-ssh-ubuntu

The FAQ section for this question is here: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

From this last link, we see that `~/.bashrc` might work.