# Jboss run with sudo

Tags: jvm, jboss5.x

I'm trying to run JBoss with sudo under certain configuration. I type: **sudo jboss *config***.
And get the following result: **path-to-jboss/bin/run.sh: 255: java: not found**

I think it could be a JVM installation issue, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like sudo is changing your $PATH, so that the java executable can no longer be found. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257616/47833) for some possible reasons why.

Comment: I mean, this is not the more appropriate approach, but it works. When you try to run jboss with sudo and you get that problem. You can add this to your run.sh (check jboss-path/bin/run.sh) and force JAVA=path-to-installed-jdk instead of asking for JAVA_HOME value. Thanks anyway bob.