# Yi failed to install

Tags: haskell

Would love to try the Yi editor, but unfortunately, it keeps failing during the installation.

First I get:

```
> cabal install yi
haskell-src-exts-1.13.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yi-0.6.5.0 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.13.0 which failed to install.
```

then when I try to install `haskell-src-exts` I am stumped by this:

```
setup: The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-src-exts-1.13.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

installing happy `cabal install happy` (version 1.18.9 at that) does not help, as it still produces the error above!

I am trying to get this going on ArchLinux. Also, Windows installation didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any potentially helpful info to be obtained from running it with `-v3`?

Answer (score 17):

`cabal` installs programs to `~/.cabal/bin` (on Unix; no idea about Windows) if they are not already installed, and does not warn you to add it to your `$PATH`; it also (unless you have the latest unreleased version, built from its repo) does not know that it has done so, because it only tracks libraries, not executables.  You will need to manually add `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to your `$PATH` so that it will be found

(**edit** be pedantic)

Comment: Hm... that didn't work. I can run `happy` fine from console, but install still can't find it.

Comment: Then we'll need to see the `-v3` output as requested by @DanielFischer above.

Comment: @drozzy Did you remember to `export` your `PATH` so that more than just your shell can see it?

Comment: Yes, but as it worked interactively, that shouldn't have been the problem.

Comment: @geekosaur: there's a difference: `~/` is expanded by your shell, so it works in bash, etc.; **however** `cabal-install` doesn't run within a shell, so it doesn't get expanded.

Comment: *sigh* I'm quite aware of it (and in fact have raised this exact point on various Haskell mailing lists in the past), *but* when it's been put in `$PATH` it's going to behave the same way interactively or in a program.  Since the OP reports it working interactively as already set in `$PATH`, it is working.

Comment: @geekosaur: no it doesn't, quite often that has failed in the past (unless cabal-install now goes and expands `$PATH` itself) whereas using `$HOME` results in it working.

Comment: I've just checked this myself: if you use `~/.cabal/bin/` in your `$PATH` then cabal-install isn't able to use it to find build-tools such as happy, alex, the various gtk2hs buildtools, etc.

Comment: @ivanm that's not the question, if you have `~` embedded in `$PATH` you are asserting that `bash` will handle it, and  it doesn't any better than `cabal` does. OP said `PATH` search worked, therefore `~` character is *not* in their `$PATH`.

Comment: @ivanm `$HOME` is the right way, but normally [I'm not a shell expert, don't know which versions handle it differently] `~` is only a problem if it's quoted in `.bash_rc` (or `.profile`, ...). If unquoted, it's expanded before `cabal` sees it, but if quoted, the `PATH` obtained from the shell contains the actual `~` character. Then you depend on the programme searching for the command to run doing tilde-expansion. The shell does, so alex, say, is callable from the command line; but cabal won't find it.

Comment: @geekosaur: using `~` works in bash for me but not with cabal-install, so it *does* make a difference.

Comment: it is important to add it in the *beginning* of the string in the $PATH variable. Otherwise you may end up executing some older version of the binary that was installed system-wide.

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu I installed happy using apt-get instead of through cabal, which worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done to install Yi with GTK+ under ArchLinux.

First, I tried `cabal install yi` and I got the same error as you.

To solve this error, I installed `happy` using this command:

```
yaourt -S happy
```

Then, I got another error because the `alex` package was needed. So, I installed it with:

```
yaourt -S alex
```

After that, I got some errors because of `gtk2hs` packages missing. I installed them with:

```
yaourt -S haskell-cairo haskell-glib haskell-gtk haskell-pango
```

Finally, I was able to install Yi with:

```
cabal install yi -fvty -fpango
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in installing hprotoc which has a dependency on haskell-src-exts.  The issue I believe was that I was running the sudo command which was modifying the path.  When I took the recommended action in the following Q&A, it resolved the issue of finding happy.

[sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

Answer (score 0):

Leksah uses Yi as a component, try installing leksah instead. I had similar error messages at one point, the haskell-src-exts error is due to running out of memory. Reboot your computer, have nothing else running except the console, and try again.