# ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils

Tags: python, importerror, enthought

I'm having a strange problem while trying to install the Python library `zenlib`, using its `setup.py` file. When I run the `setup.py` file, I get an import error, saying

> ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils`

but I do have such a module, and I can import it on the python command line without any trouble.  Why might I be getting this import error?

I think that the problem may have to do with the fact that I am using [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/product/enthought-python-distribution/), which I installed right beforehand, rather than using the Python 2.7 that came with Ubuntu 12.04.

More background:
Here's exactly what I get when trying to run setup.py:

```
enwe101@enwe101-PCL:~/zenlib/src$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils
```

But it works from the command line:

```
>>> from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
>>> 
>>> from fake.package import noexist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fake.package
```

Note the first import worked and the second throws an error.  Compare this to the first few lines of setup.py:

```
#from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import os.path
```

I made sure that the Enthought Python Distribution and not the python that came with Ubuntu is what is run by default by prepending my bash $PATH environment variable by editing `~/.bashrc`, adding this as the last line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/epd/bin:$PATH
```

and indeed `which python` spits out `/usr/local/epd/bin/python`... not knowing what else to try, I went into my site packages directory, (`/usr/local/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages`) and give full permissions (r,w,x) to `Cython`, `Distutils`, `build_ext.py`, and the `__init__.py` files.  Probably silly to try, and it changed nothing.

Can't think of what to try next!? Any ideas?

Comment: I can't think of anything, but what's in your `sys.path`?

Comment: does `sudo python -c 'import Cython.Distutils'` work?

Comment: My experiemnt yielded the same result, I di an install of Python 2.7 on ubuntu 12-04, cython, numpy,scipy. Same error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils   . None of the answers seem to have resolved this. Dear Experts HELP!!!

Comment: For people who find this via google: `sudo apt-get install python-dev; sudo pip install cython`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your sudo is not getting the right python. This is a known behaviour of sudo in Ubuntu. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) for more info. You need to make sure that sudo calls the right python, either by using the full path:

```
sudo /usr/local/epd/bin/python setup.py install
```

or by doing the following (in bash):

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: It had been awhile since I posted this question, but this indeed was how I solved the problem.  A more recent post reminded me that it was still open.  Use @user91279 's suggestion to find the correct path for you.

Answer (score 84):

Install Cython:

```
pip install cython
```

Comment: This worked for me, but not for the latest version of cython[0.22] but for a previous version 0.21.2

Comment: Indeed the solution for packages that do not explicitly include `cython` in their list of dependences, or do not manage their dependencies properly (which was [`hmmlearn`](https://pypi.org/project/hmmlearn/) 0.1.1 in my case).

Comment: I needed python-dev for python lib headers

Answer (score 11):

For python3 use

```
sudo apt-get install cython3
```

For python2 use

```
sudo apt-get install cython
```

Details can be read at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/388750/install-cython-on-python-3-x)

Comment: Thank you!
I'm using Debian Buster on Windows 10 WSL, in this specific case that was the solution

Answer (score 9):

Run

> `which python`

Thats the path to the python that your system has defaulted too 
then go to @tiago's method of:

> `sudo <output of which python> setup.py install`

Answer (score 5):

I only got one advice for you : Create a virtualenv. This will ensure you have only one version of python and all your packages installed locally (and not on your entire system).
Should be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In the CLI-python, import sys and look what's inside sys.path
Then try to use `export PYTHONPATH=whatyougot`

Answer (score 1):

Running the following commands resolved the issue for me in ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev    
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo apt-get install libsystemd-daemon-dev
sudo pip install cython
```

This link helped me: https://github.com/trezor/python-trezor/issues/40

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this again in modern times. The solution was simple:

```
pip uninstall cython && pip install cython
```

Answer (score 1):

Read like a thousand of these threads and finally got it for Python 3. (replace pip with pip3 if you have that kind of installation, and run `pip uninstall cython` if you have tried other solutions before running any of these)

Mac:

```
brew install cython
pip install --upgrade cython
```

Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install cython3 python-dev  
pip install --upgrade cython
```

Windows (must have conda, and MinGW already in path)

```
conda install cython
conda install --upgrade cython
```

Answer (score 0):

That is easy.

You could try `install cython` package first.

It will upgrade your **easy_install** built in python.

Answer (score 0):

I had dependency from third party library on Cython, didn't manage to build the project on Travis due to the ImportError. In case someone needs it - before installing requirements.txt run this command:

> pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"

Installing GCC also might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with [sipsimple](https://sipsimpleclient.org/installation/). The problem was solved by installing an older cython, I've used `pip install 'cython<3'`, got `cython-0.29.37`, and it seems to have the `Cython.Distutils` available.

Of course, it's best to install such dependencies to a venv.

Answer (score -1):

Just install Cython from
http://cython.org/#download
and install it using this command

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Then run the command

```
sudo python -c 'import Cython.Distutils'
```

and it will be installed and the error message will disappear.