# Installing Cython encountered loop dependency

Tags: python, installation, cython

I am installing cython to my python.

I unzipped the tar.gz and did the build-install routine.

Then, setup.py told me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 238, in <module>
    compile_cython_modules(cython_profile, cython_compile_more, cython_with_refnanny)
  File "setup.py", line 170, in compile_cython_modules
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils
```

So it means, I need cython to install cython?

Or did I miss something important?

Comment: What about `pip install cython`?

Comment: @KevinGuan sadly, I am in a client without access to the internet. ez_install or pip won't work

Comment: Well, maybe check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108461/python-importerror-cython-distutils)?

Comment: Thank you. I checked around path and it's normal. And I don't have one cython previously

Comment: Hmm...are you using Linux or Windows? If you're using Linux maybe you could use package manager to do it.

Comment: I think maybe I'v found the reason.  'rz' command did not commit a intact transfer but it gave no error. The package I unzipped was a broken one. I scp-ed another and finally got it right. Thank you for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason lays in 'rz' command which did not commit a intact transfer but gave no error.

The package I unzipped was a broken one uploaded by others. I downloaded another and finally got it right.

suggestion: use following command to check your package's integrity first.

```
>md5sum sth.tar.gz                show checksum
>du -h st.tar.gz                  show human-readable file size
```

And thanks Kevin Guan for the suggestions and help.