# Unable to install TA-Lib on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Python Ta-Lib in Ubuntu,but when I run:

```
pip install TA-Lib
```

I get this error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YfCSFn/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-swmI7D-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YfCSFn/TA-Lib/
```

I already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and installed Ta-lib

How can I fix this?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` implies python2 usually.  You probably need `sudo apt install python-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like other people had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498495/error-when-installing-using-pip).

To quote the accepted answer:

> Seems that your PiP can't access Setuptools as per the "import
>   setuptools" in the error. Try the below first then try running your
>   pip install again.

```
> sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Or if it doesn't work to quote his comment:

> Try this 'sudo -H pip install TA-Lib'

As Filipe Ferminiano said in comment if this still doesn't fix it then you can try what is said on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108461/python-importerror-cython-distutils) .

To quote the accepted answer once again:

```
Your sudo is not getting the right python. This is a known behaviour of sudo in Ubuntu. See this question for more info. You need to make sure that sudo calls the right python, either by using the full path:
sudo /usr/local/epd/bin/python setup.py install
```

> or by doing the following (in bash):

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
sudo python setup.py install
```

Here is the question [he's talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

Please give credit to the one of the accepted answer if it fix your problem.

Comment: Is it doing that for every pip install or just for this one?

Comment: Just for this one.

Comment: Did you try what other people said in the link? Some said to try to upgrade your pip with "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"

Comment: I tried, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108461/python-importerror-cython-distutils

Comment: I must say, first time seeing a "Your sudo is not getting the right python". I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: if I do 'sudo -H pip install TA-Lib', it went weel. but I can not see it by: pip list in my venv

Answer (score 36):

I am ***able*** to load in python3.

**Steps:**

1. download from http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
2. **untar** `tar -xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz`
3. `cd /../ta-lib`
4. `./configure --prefix=/usr`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install`
7. `sudo apt upgrade`
8. `pip install ta-lib` or `pip install TA-Lib`
9. **Check** `import talib`

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04! Thanks!

Comment: 8 did not work.

  Building wheel for ta-lib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Answer (score 4):

This has always been a tricky one, but I had made a script that has served me loyally in several Ubuntu physical, VM, and server instances (including GitHub Actions).

It's a little long but it's comprehensive and has worked in every Ubuntu instance I've needed it for. It includes a few precautionary steps that have previously caused errors.

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt install wget -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt install python3.10-dev -y
sudo apt-get install python3-dev -y

wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib

wget 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD' -O './config.guess'
wget 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD' -O './config.sub'
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

sudo rm -rf ta-lib
sudo rm -rf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

pip install ta-lib
```

It consists of many steps...

1. Update built-in packages using apt.
2. Add the deadsnakes repo.
3. Install `build-essential` and `python-dev` (`python3-dev`, `python3.10-dev`).
4. Download the TA-Lib tarball with `wget`.
5. Download the updated make recognizer files to prevent common issues with `make` and `make install`.
6. `make` TA-Lib and `make install` it.
7. Clean up the mess.
8. Install with `pip` to make sure everything worked out. (`pip` will install the latest version of TA-Lib, `0.4.24`, even though we can only download the source for `0.4.0`. This works fine.)

Because I use this frequently, I turned it into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/preritdas/7b1a4fcd6b3835e80cea4c27295464d4), for the purpose of accessing the script directly with `curl`.

Just grab a raw link from the [Gist page](https://gist.github.com/preritdas/7b1a4fcd6b3835e80cea4c27295464d4) and use it like below.

```bash
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/preritdas/bunchofrandomstuffhere/install-talib-ubuntu.sh | sudo bash
```

Make sure you're `sudo` activated before running the command to prevent issues. It will run all the above commands as a script and install TA-Lib in about 4-5 minutes (average, in my experience).

Here's a shell recording of this working on a fresh server instance of Ubuntu 22.04.

[image: asciicast]

All in all, I hope this helps; for me, it made a once frustrating and volatile process easy.

Comment: this saves my life!

Comment: Thanks a LOT!! Had been trying this since morning.  This works :)