# unable to import TA-Lib - Python

Tags: python, anaconda, ta-lib

I am trying to importTA-Lib in python but getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/home/arque/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/talib/**init**.py", >line 43, in 
>     from ._ta_lib import (
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib._ta_lib'

Steps that I follow to install:

```
1. wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
2. tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
3. cd ta-lib/
4. ./configure --prefix=/usr
5. make
6. sudo make install
7. pip install TA-Lib
```

`TA-Lib` successfully installed but when I'm trying to import the same, getting the error mentioned above.

Also tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406213/unable-to-install-ta-lib-on-ubuntu) but didn't work.

Using **Linux Ubuntu 32bit and python 3.6**

Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the process I used to fix the problem when I got this error - however I'm using a 64-bit Windows installation, so you'll need to make some changes along the way!

- Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib and download the relevant  *.whl file (depending on which python version you’re using, and depending on whether you have a 32 bit or 64 bit operating system)
- Copy the whl file into the C:\Users\your_name directory
- Go to Anaconda and click on the Environments tab and open the Terminal window (from the Base(root) environment arrow)
- In the Terminal window type “conda list” to see if TA-Lib is already available and continue if not
- Type “conda update conda” to ensure you have the latest version installed
- You’ll install TA-Lib using pip so ensure you have the latest version of pip by typing “python -m pip install --upgrade pip”
- Then install the TA-Lib package by typing “pip install TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl” (or whatever the name of your *.whl file is)
- Check to see that it’s installed by typing “conda list” and finding it on the list

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

!pip install ta

For installing ta on kaggle platform