# Error Installing TA-Lib on Ubuntu 16 Python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ta-lib

I am on Ubuntu 16:

```
$ pip -V
pip 18.0 from /home/XYZ-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
XYZ-ubuntu@XYZubuntu-desktop:~/Desktop/MCF/BitMEX-simple-trading-robot-master$ pip3 -V
pip 18.0 from /home/usm-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

When I run this:

> pip install TA-lib

I receive the following error:

```
$ pip install TA-lib
Collecting TA-lib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/05/d4c6a778d7a7de0be366bc4a850b4ffaeac2abad927f95fa8ba6f355a082/TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/usm-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from TA-lib) (1.15.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-lib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for TA-lib ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-72o18u12/TA-lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-3i94vijy --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  running build_ext
  building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/usm-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib/_ta_lib.o
  talib/_ta_lib.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for TA-lib
  Running setup.py clean for TA-lib
Failed to build TA-lib
Installing collected packages: TA-lib
  Running setup.py install for TA-lib ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-72o18u12/TA-lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-bsagqzqb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    running build_ext
    building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/usm-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib/_ta_lib.o
    talib/_ta_lib.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-72o18u12/TA-lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-bsagqzqb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-72o18u12/TA-lib/
```

I've followed everything here -

> [Unable to install TA-Lib on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406213/unable-to-install-ta-lib-on-ubuntu)

I've spent hours on this and googling it to no avail. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: I have python3-dev installed.

Comment: try to find Python.h on your pc with `locate Python.h` check the paths. According to your log gcc compiler expects to find it in `/usr/include/python3.6m/`

Comment: had the same issue and could solve it by installing the headers `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I had conflicts between Python 2.7 and 3.5/3.6.

After upgrading I changed the alias to python3 using `nano ~/.bashrc` and adding line `alias python = python3`.

Then installed TA-lib by running command:

> python3 -m pip install TA-lib

Now everything is working fine. Thanks

Comment: not working for me..  Python 3.9.7