# rvmsudo rvm gemset import, .gems file not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos, rvm

I am trying to do a `rvmsudo rvm gemset import` but I am getting this error:

```
No *.gems file found.
```

The `.gems` file is called `default.gems`.

I've tried doing a `rvmsudo rvm gemset import default` doesn't work either.

But when I issue a `rvm gemset import` without elevating to root using `rvmsudo`, it tries to install the gems in my `default.gems` file. I suspect `rvmsudo` is changing the path and fails to find the `.gems` file in my current working directory. Is there a way to prevent `rvmsudo` from changing the path?

I've tried to follow the instructions in [sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use `rvmsudo`, it's for special occasions only, and most of time - it's safer to not use it!

if you are using multiuser or mixed mode installation - then you are better with adding yourself to `rvm` group and running:

```
rvmsudo rvm get head
```

to update the installation - yes this time it's ok to use `*sudo`