# ImportError: No module named vtkRenderingOpenGLPython

Tags: python, vtk

I have installed vtk through the conda-forge channel. But get the below error upon importing vtk.

`ImportError: No module named vtkRenderingOpenGLPython`

Following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495285/importerror-no-module-named-vtkcommonpython) I added the path of my vtk package to PYTHONPATH. Including the path to the vtk-7.0.0-py27_2/lib where I see libvtkRenderingOpenGL-7.0.so

But no luck, import still does not find it. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong are appreciated.