# LD_LIBRARY_PATH with sudo python

Tags: python, environment-variables, sudo

I'm trying to use a newer Python (2.7.3) with an old CentOS.

I have a recipe to install python to a non-standard location:

```
 ./configure --prefix=#{install_path} --with-threads --enable-shared --with-zlib=/usr/include
 make
 make install
```

I set the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables to find `bin/python` and the `.so` files using `/etc/profile.d/`. This seems to mostly work.

With a non-root user, I get the right Python:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 24 2012, 15:18:59) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

With a root user, I get the right Python:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo su
[root@localhost vagrant]# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 24 2012, 15:18:59) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

However, the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hack seems to be a little wonked when using sudo:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo python
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Even though the variables look right:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo which python
/opt/Python-2.7.3/bin/python
```

Adding `Defaults env_keep += "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` to `/etc/sudoers` does not work.

`sudo -i python` does work.
`sudo -E python` does not work.

I'm curious what I could do to get `sudo` to pick up the right Python without `-i`?

related:

[sudo changes PATH - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593336/odd-path-behaviour-on-centos-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this blog post](http://koansys.com/tech/building-python-with-enable-shared-in-non-standard-location). You can forego the use of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by linking with `LDFLAGS` in configure. Where `#{ldlibpath}` is `#{install_path}/lib`:

```
./configure --prefix=#{install_path} --with-threads --enable-shared \
--with-zlib=/usr/include LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath #{ldlibpath}"
```

As noted in the blog post, you will need to mkdir this ldlibpath before running configure.