# ubuntu 10.04 sudo and path

Tags: path, ubuntu-10.04, sudo

Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

I have seen the posts regarding sudo and PATH on various sites including stackoverflow. I think this is different, so I'm pretty sure it is not a duplicate (but I'm not sure).

1) First, the non-sudo path to ruby:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/ruby/bin/ruby
```

2) and then the sudo path to ruby:

```
$ sudo which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Ok, so far so good. The path changed when I used sudo.

3) But here's the part I don't get:

```
$ sudo echo $PATH
/home/cm6/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:<snipped>
```

ie, the path to ruby is in the $PATH variable set when I use sudo.

4) And a little stranger again:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/cm6/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:<snipped>
```

This time, no sudo, but the $PATH variable content is the same as that for sudo.

Given $PATH variable is the same with or without sudo, why did the "which ruby" give me different answers? It's as if the $PATH variable doesn't hold the real PATH under sudo.

So, finally, my question: how do I get the real/accurate/correct PATH used by sudo?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo changes PATH - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo echo $PATH` evals $PATH before calling sudo.

to find out for sure:

```
sudo -s
echo $PATH
```

You need to add the PATH variable to env_keep in /etc/sudoers

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I just going to post that this works too: `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.   I did add the path to /etc/sudoers and all is working fine.

Comment: yes, `sudo sh ...` would work as well.  I just prefer the shorter version with `sudo -s`, less to type :)