# varying python versions installing eric on ubuntu 16.04 using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to install eric6 on ubuntu 16.04 but am running into problems which look like issues with different python versions. I am running in virtualenv but it doesn't seem to be helping. Here's what I did:

Set up virtualenv:

```
kira@machine:~/Downloads/eric6-18.03$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 ~/envs/eric
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/kira/envs/eric/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/kira/envs/eric/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

Activated:

```
kira@machine:~/envs/ericc$ source bin/activate
(eric) kira@machine:~/envs/ericc$ eric
```

Installed qt:

```
(eric) kira@machine:~/Downloads$ ./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.2-online.run
```

(Seemed to install successfully - confirmed in dialog box)

Installed qscintilla:

```
(eric) kira@machine:~/Downloads$ pip3 install qscintilla
Collecting qscintilla
Using cached QScintilla-2.10.3-5.10.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyQt5>=5.10.1 (from qscintilla)
Using cached PyQt5-5.10.1-5.10.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 (from PyQt5>=5.10.1->qscintilla)
Using cached sip-4.19.8-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: sip, PyQt5, qscintilla
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.10.1 qscintilla-2.10.3 sip-4.19.8
```

Check python version, install eric - note picks up python version 2.7.12:

```
(eric) kira@machine:~/Downloads/eric6-18.03$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
(eric) kira@machine:~/Downloads/eric6-18.03$ sudo python install.py
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 2.7.12
Sorry, please install PyQt5. 
Error: No module named PyQt5.QtCore
```

Tried without sudo, picks up python version 3.5.2:

```
(eric) kira@machine:~/Downloads/eric6-18.03$ python install.py
Checking dependencies  
Python Version: 3.5.2
Found PyQt5
Found pyuic5
Found QScintilla2
Found QtGui
Found QtNetwork
Found QtPrintSupport
Found QtSql
Found QtSvg
Found QtWidgets
Found QtWebEngineWidgets
Qt Version: 5.10.1
sip Version: 4.19.8
PyQt Version: 5.10.1
QScintilla Version: 2.10.3
All dependencies ok.

Cleaning up old installation ...

Creating configuration file ...

Compiling user interface files ...

Compiling source files ...

Installing eric6 ...
Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/eric6_api'
Try install with admin rights.

Installation complete.
```

I assume the problem is something to do with the python version changing but don't know how to fix it.

Kira

Comment: you have to install using sudo otherwise it won't work

Comment: I used sudo first (see above, after installing qscintilla) and it picked up the wrong python version, and could not find PyQt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - 'sudo python' execs the command directly so was using python2 despite being run in a virtual environment. (As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441440/sudo-python-runs-old-python-version)). Eric now installs without errors. (But doesn't run, a different issue)