# PermissionDeniedError on Google Deep Learning VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I try to run a simple TF model training on a [Google Deep Learning VM](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/tensorflow_start_instance#without-gpus).

I use the standard settings, get the VM running, use gcloud to ssh into the VM and install all the packages. However, whenever I run a `.py` file that writes some output (e.g. `generate_tfrecord.py` ) or needs to open some file (`model_main_tf2.py`), I keep getting a PermissionDeniedError; Permission denied.

If I run `sudo su` before, the error disappears, but then the VM uses python 2.7 and TF is not installed. I am lacking some knowledge how VMs really work, but I assume that some virtual environment is used? If so, there should be some workaround to use python files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your "normal" user and the root user have a different set of environment variables, including `$PATH`, which tells the shell which directories to search for executable files. Here you can find a complete explanation of the environment variables [1].

Also, there is a very good explanation and a workaround on how to run the Python version you want with the root user in the following link [2]. However, I recommend you to use a virtual environment instead, as virtual environments offer several advantages as you can see in this document [3].

[1] https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables

[2] [sudo python runs old python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441440/sudo-python-runs-old-python-version)

[3] https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html