# I screwed up the system version of Python Pip on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-12.10

I wanted to update pip on my main install of Python, specifically to get the list command. Which also includes the list- updates capability.

So I ran:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

All looked good on the install but then I went to run pip and got this: (end of install included if it helps)

```
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing pip-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
tom@tom-sam:~$ pip list -o
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
tom@tom-sam:~$ pip
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Somewhat obviously I'm hosed since this is my system install of python.. I read a few answers here but have not been able to determine the easiest fix.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the `python-pip` package? I believe it provides the /usr/bin/pip program.

Comment: instead of calling "pip" did you try "pip-2.7". Sometimes it is just the symlink that is broken.

Comment: pip-2.7 works, how do I fix so it just gets with "pip" That is how do I fix the symlink? I'm still beginnig to get symlinks :-)

Comment: unutbu  using what command?

Comment: Actually I did try re installing pip with easy_install, no help..

Comment: Ahh I found the pip symlink in /usr/bin and is says it is broken as  "This link cannot be used  because its target "pip-2.7" does not exist" How to fix?

Comment: What does `which pip-2.7` report back?

Comment: Which pip-2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 but I do not see a pip-2.7 file in /usr/bin

Comment: Looks like `pip-2.7` in `/usr/bin` was possibly removed by the install you ran (or something else uninstalled it). You can recreate a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` with `ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip` and then remove `pip` from `/usr/bin`.

Comment: did not work?  sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/pip': File exists
tom@tom-sam:~$

Comment: In that case, I guess your `/usr/bin` takes precedence over `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`. You can do a `sudo rm /usr/bin/pip` to remove the broken symlink in there. After that, `pip` should work as the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` already exists.

Comment: damn, just what I though, I removed it and still getting bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Comment: This did it sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 /usr/bin/pip

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had the same message on linux.

```
/usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

but then checked which pip was being called.

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

On my debian wheezy machine I fixed it doing following...

```
/usr/local/bin/pip uninstall pip  
apt-get remove python-pip  
apt-get install python-pip
```

====================================
This was due to mixup installing with `apt-get` and updating with `pip install -U pip`.

These also installed libraries at 2 different places which caused problems for me.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: This did it sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 /usr/bin/pip

Comment: You really might want @boredcoding's answer over this one.

Comment: The answer is unfortunately incorrect *unless* you `hash -r` first.

Comment: no need to uninstall or reinstall python-pip, if messed up env variables then put a symbolic link as suggested by @dartdog.
As uninstall/reinstalling method will bring back the older version of pip 9.0 instead of 19.2.

Answer (score 231):

Before getting happy with apt-get removes and installs. It's worthwhle to reset your bash cache.

```
hash -r
```

Bash will cache the path to pip using the distrubtion install (apt-get) which is /usr/bin/pip. If you're still in the same shell session, due to the cache, after updating pip from pip your shell will still look in /usr/bin/ and not /usr/local/bin/

for example:

```
$apt-get install python-pip
$which pip
/usr/bin/pip

$pip install -U pip
$which pip
/usr/bin/pip

$hash -r
$which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: I ran each command as stated above (for me: after executing _pip install -U pip_, console returned _/usr/local/bin/pip_) - everything worked, and I could run _pip freeze_ again!

Comment: That was awesome :o)

For the life of it I couldn't figure out why pip wasn't being executed when i could see /usr/local/bin in the PATH

Comment: Non distirbution software/libs/docs etc... are typically installed in /usr/local/xxx and not in /usr/xxx.

if you echo $PATH you'll see /usr/local/bin listed before /usr/bin. This will ensure that things we installed outside of apt are considered first.

This is a common issue with nodejs too as the exe is named nodejs and not node. Npm wants node. So we solve the problem by symlinking /usr/bin/nodejs to /usr/local/bin/node

Hope this helps to understand why this works.

Comment: @etayluz Login as root user, type 'which pip' and verify it is /usr/local/bin/pip and not /usr/bin/pip. If it is /usr/bin/pip than the root path variable is not looking in /usr/local/bin/ before /usr/bin.

'hash -r' is just a cache reset it will do nothing for you if you path variable is actually wrong.

When invoking sudo without telling bash to keep your logged in users environment active it will activate the root users environment.

There are methods to retaining your environment when running sudo.
for example.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why

Comment: @etayluz To add to that, hash -r will only reset the cache for the logged in user. The solution could be as simple as just logging in as root and typing 'hash -r' or just adding /usr/local/bin; to the beginning of the root users path environment variable (or at least ensuring it's before /usr/bin).

Comment: This really helped me, after reinstalling and getting "No such file or directory" when running pip I used hash -r as you said and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem running Mint 18.1 after upgrading pip. I got it resolved simply by closing and opening the terminal.

Comment: This actually worked for me too.  I'm glad I read this before I went and did a bunch of uninstalling/reinstalling.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem as @dartdog and thanks to @Martin Mohan and @warvariuc I was able to fully uninstall pip

Unfortunately using the command

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

Was installing an old version of pip so after doing

```
/usr/local/bin/pip uninstall pip  
apt-get remove python-pip
```

To install the latest pip version I got the ***get-pip.py*** file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

And once in the file directory from the command line executed the command `python get-pip.py` hope it helps someone

Also some of the commands need sudo
good luck!!

Comment: You can update the system wide pip from pip with 'sudo pip install -U pip'

sudo will, barring special cases, be required anytime you want to alter the system python, which includes using pip to install packages into the system wide packages folders.

Comment: For Python 2.7, use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead

Answer (score 0):

These two answers in other threads helped me out:

1. Re-installing pip:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997795/9377685
2. pip started working after step 1, but kept showing an error:

`RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)`

This answer helped in upgrading the cryptography and PyOpenSSL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51284877/9377685

Answer (score -2):

I was using pip with Python 3.5.2. Then I messed up during upgrade to Python 3.6 and I decided to revert to 3.5. After I removed pip-3.6, `pip3` was pointing to `/usr/local/bin/pip3`, but the symlink to the actual pip install directory was missing. I fixed it with

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip3`