# Why is PIP raising an AssertionError on pip freeze?

Tags: pip

My console:

```
desarrollador@desarrollador-HP-14-Notebook-PC1:~$ pip freeze  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main  
    self.run(options, args)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py", line 68, in run  
   req = pip.FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, dependency_links, find_tags=find_tags)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 156, in from_dist  
    assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='  
AssertionError
```

I installed the tornado package and this happened since. How can I fix it?

Comment: you are providing very little information. What version of pip are you using? Did you have a look at the various threads here at SO with the same or similar error message? It might be related to `distribute`. Do you happen to still have a version of `distribute` installed?

Comment: there's no thread like this in SO. I'm using the most recent version.

Comment: I'm getting this, too. I'm using pip version 1.5.4. `pip install` works just fine.

Comment: `sudo easy_install -U pip` would fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reason: The python-pip package in Ubuntu 12.04 is seriously outdated and has some bugs with certain package names (as I can see) and cannot parse them correctly.

Solution: install a newer version of pip, via easy_install.

Comment: I just realized i have several versions of pip on my $PATH !   the first pip on the path was the older version.    run each of the pip's with pip -V to check which one is the latest (today: 7.1.2) and remove the old ones.

Comment: ended up deleting / removing / purging all   the 'pip's i had, and then installing the latest.  i guess it's because there are 5 different ways to install pip, and each one does it a little bit differently.

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me (running Ubuntu, both 12 and 14 LTS):

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U pip
```

Upgrade to the latest version of setuptools in order to be able to upgrade to the latest version of pip, and upgrade to the latest version of pip to get a version that has fixed the AssertException error.

Comment: sometimes you have add `sudo` if root had installed `pip`

Answer (score 15):

Your pip may be outdated. Even in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the pip version it installed using `apt-get install python-pip` was 1.5.4. Try updating pip manually, and possibly the new packages again as well.

```
pip --version # 1.5.4
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
pip --version # 6.0.8
hash -r # reset bash cache
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution at [this link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1418#issuecomment-68882573).

`pip install setuptools==7.0`

Comment: Try running `pip list`. If your problem is similar to mine, pip will list most of the packages before throwing an error on the package that's creating the problem. Then take a look at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` (or wherever your packages are installed) and see if you can figure out what the next package is alphabetically. Maybe that will get you the information you need to solve it?

Comment: I could manage to upgrade pip! :D I was using pip 1.0 (the one that comes with ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: This did work for me temorarily, but installing other packages I install update setup tools so downgrading does not appear to be an option for me.

Answer (score 3):

First, I ran Martin Mohan's solution:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip uninstall pip
apt-get remove python-pip
apt-get install python-pip
```

Then, boredcoding's ultimately fixed the problem, both solutions are found near bottom of thread: [I screwed up the system version of Python Pip on Ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237490/i-screwed-up-the-system-version-of-python-pip-on-ubuntu-12-10)

```
$apt-get install python-pip
$which pip
/usr/bin/pip

$pip install -U pip
$which pip
/usr/bin/pip

$hash -r
$which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

The logic behind these two fix are stated in the thread (linked above), so I will refrain from going into each here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to an old version of `pip` being installed. 
Run the following command to install a new version of `pip`:

```
sudo easy_install -U pip.
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit late, but one thing I found was there are 2 or three versions of pip installed (depending on what you installed)

pip - the OS version installed, freeze doesn't work and it can be out of date
pip2 - the newer one installed but upgrading pip via pip etc
pip3 - installed if you have python3 and python2 installed at the same time.

You can either change which pip gets used in $PATH, or do what I did:

**pip2 freeze** (which does work on ubuntu14 if you have more than one option for python)