# why am I getting AssertionError when running pip freeze on mac?

Tags: python, ios, terminal, pip

I've tried the solutions offered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711184/why-is-pip-raising-an-assertionerror-on-pip-freeze) SO question.

I'm still getting the following:

```
~ $pip freeze
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/freeze.py", line 73, in run
req = pip.FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, dependency_links, find_tags=find_tags)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 194, in from_dist
assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
AssertionError

Storing complete log in filepath/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: so you have the latest version?

Comment: I ran `sudo easy_install pip` and it says `pip 1.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth`

Comment: Use `sudo pip install -U pip`, that is not the latest version, `6.1.1` is the latest

Comment: no worries, I would stick to pip when installing/upgrading packages.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  will do.  If you have a sec, can you say why?

Comment: pip is and has been the de-facto standard package manager for python for a long time, since python 3.4 it is actually included in the install.