# Unable to uninstall with pip

Tags: python, pip

As doing exercise 46 on [learnpythonthehardway](http://learnpythonthehardway.org), I run into an issue with uninstallation.

**Background**

My package showed is created as:

```
├── bin
├── docs
├── HELLOWORLD
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── HELLOWORLD_tests.py
    ├── __init__.py
```

THe way I installed the packages:

- run `python setup.py sdist` to create a `tar.gz` and en `egg-info` file
- use `pip install`, pointing at the `tar.gz` above to install.

Thus, it was installed successfully, as:

- The package shows in `/urs/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- The package is usable (able to import and run successfully)

**The Problem**

However, the problem is that I was unable to uninstall it using `pip uninstall HELLOWORLD`, as it shows this message 
`Can't uninstall 'helloworld'. No files were found to uninstall.`

What step do I miss?

Comment: It seems that either `pip` converts the name to lowercase either you typed it like that. It's not so good to name your Python module with all caps.

Comment: I tried with lower/upper case, but still the same message.

Comment: Does `helloworld` show up when you use `pip list`?

Comment: It does. 
Also, I tried reinstalling with "helloworld", not "HELLOWORLD", same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, it was because `pip` was installed via `apt-get`, thus outdated version.

Came to know about it since I got the same error as this: 
[Why is PIP raising an AssertionError on pip freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711184/why-is-pip-raising-an-assertionerror-on-pip-freeze)

I had to update `pip` as `pip install -U pip`,and the problem is solved.