# pip: no module named _internal

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem when I try to use pip in any way. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4

I should say that I've used it already, and I never had any problem, but starting today when I use any command I always get the same error (as an example using `pip --upgrade`).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal
```

I have tried doing `sudo apt-get remove python-pip` followed by `sudo apt-get install python-pip` but nothing changed.

Comment: Make sure that `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` precedes `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @WayBehind I did found a solution. I noticed that using `python -m pip` everything works just fine. Beside that, I removed the file `/usr/local/bin/pip`, now calling `pip -V` return `pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. Everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: I still have the same problem, I am using pip in conda environment , python 2.7  and I am using pip install ipdb. Any idea about this?

Comment: Followed the steps plus the -H flag:
`sudo -H python3.7 get-pip.py --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 228):

This did it for me:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Environment: OSX && Python installed via [brew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python)

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution for me using python3.

Comment: this did not work for me. what @Grimdrem   did is what I ended up doing. I had(in the past) installed pip for all (using sudo or something)...and my upgrade was with --user so the other install still hung around...removing it from /usr/local/bin and from my main python's package folder (not --user's) did the trick.

Comment: Strangely this has fixed it here, too. I was to upgrade #searx to latest commit.

Comment: Ran into this on Ubuntu on WSL. I also use `pyenv`, but had somehow muffed the system python which `vim` uses. This put things where they needed to be.and now `taskwiki` works again. Whew!

Comment: This worked on ubutnu as well

Comment: If your system is old enough to have python2 still present, you'll need to
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` instead.

Comment: This gives me: `/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`.

Answer (score 89):

An answer from [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal) works.

For pip2.7, you can at first  `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`, then `python2.7 get-pip.py --force-reinstall` to reinstall pip.

Problem solved. Also works for python3.

Answer (score 78):

This solution works for me:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

or use **sudo** for elevated permissions (`sudo python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall`).

Of course, you can also use `python` instead of `python3` ;)

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026848/500671)

Answer (score 39):

Are you using python 2 or python 3? The following commands could be different!

1. run `python3 -m pip --version` to see if you have pip installed.
2. if yes, run `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`.
3. if no, run `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, and do it again.

Comment: The first two steps solved this problem on my macOS with an M1 chip...

Comment: The third step worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 22):

Refer to this [issue list](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5373)

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

works for me under Mac OS

For `python3`, may try `sudo easy_install-3.x pip` depends on the python 3.x version. Or `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip`

Comment: That's old Python2. On Python3 Ubuntu at least you should also run `sudo easy_install-3.4 pip` or similar.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me when I have to upgrade pip 20.2.3 to pip 21.0 on MacOS.  Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

This issue maybe due to common user do not have privilege to access packages py file.
1. root user can run 'pip list'
2. other common user cannot run 'pip list'

```
[~]$ pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal
```

Check pip py file privilege.

```
[root@]# ll /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/  
合計 24  
-rw-------  1 root root   24  6月  7 16:57 __init__.py  
-rw-------  1 root root  163  6月  7 16:57 __init__.pyc  
-rw-------  1 root root  629  6月  7 16:57 __main__.py  
-rw-------  1 root root  510  6月  7 16:57 __main__.pyc  
drwx------  8 root root 4096  6月  7 16:57 _internal  
drwx------ 18 root root 4096  6月  7 16:57 _vendor
```

solution : root user login and run

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/lib/python2.7
```

fix this issue.

Comment: Finally a logical explanation of what the problem actually is. Re-installing might solve the problem but that's the real reason it is not working in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. In our case, it was the permission problem.

Comment: Note: pay attention to the python path in the error. In my case it was `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/` on RHEL 7

Comment: I don't think you want to make all of the text files there executable...

Comment: This appears to have been the necessary fix, even for python3.9. I couldn't run any of the other commands for pip until I did this.
Also, per einpoklum, you might `sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/*.pth` and `sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/*.txt` (per whichever appropriate /usr/... directory) after everything else.

Answer (score 17):

In file "/usr/local/bin/pip" **change** `from pip._internal import main` to `from pip import main`

Comment: This worked for me for python2.7 and the corresponding pip2.7, other answers to this question apply for using pip with python3

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this issue when `PYTHONPATH` was set to include the built-in `site-packages` directory. Since Python looks there automatically it is unnecessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered the same problem and in my case, it turns out this is a conflict between the python installation in my virtualenv and the site-wide python (Ubuntu).
What solves it for me is to run pip in this way, to force usage of the correct python installation (in my vortualenv):

```
python3 -m pip install PACKAGE
```

instead of

```
pip3 install PACKAGE
```

I realised this when I tried to follow some of the answers here that suggest re-installing pip and the error output I got was pointing to an existing site-wide python library path although I had activated my virtualenv. 
Worth trying before deleting and re-installing stuff.

Comment: As mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50737296/1340995 it's a permission issue. I found that using pip with `python3 -m pip` solves this issue as well, probably because `python` has permission to execute and it doesn't need pip to have the +x permission as it's just loading the file and not executing it.

Answer (score 5):

For me

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
```

solved the issue. [Reference](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599#issuecomment-414157896)

Comment: worked on MacOS, thanks! (don't reinstall, turns out it was a conflicting installation)

Answer (score 4):

Checking from [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), this command worked to me:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Comment: I am building python from source inside Docker. Then I am adding a virtual environment in that python version. pip command does not work. After all attempts I did from over and there, only this has worked for me (when running it in that virtual environment). THANKS!

Comment: Only thing that worked for me was similar: python -m ensurepip --default-pip This reinstalled pip in the venv

Answer (score 3):

Its probably due to a version conflict, try to run this, it will remove the older pip somehow.

```
sudo apt remove python pip
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this appears to be the solution for a Debian-like distro (_e.g._, Ubuntu 16.04) where the `python-pip` package was installed at the distro level, and `get-pip.py` had been used for a user-specific version of `pip` which was also in the `$PATH`. I `sudo apt-get remove`d the `python-pip` package (2.7) and used the one in my ~/.local/bin instead. No more error message.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this error by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

It will remove the previously installed pip and reinstall it.

Comment: tried everything still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me, but only one thing:
I used sudo in front of the command and it is working fine.

Comment: My case was weirder because "sudo" still gave me the same error. I had to switch to root (sudo su on ubuntu) to be able to do pip3.5 list and pip3.5 install :|

Answer (score 2):

I met the same error on Windows when I tried to install a package via pip3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip3.6.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

My python is installed via Anaconda. I solved this issue by reinstalling pip via conda:

```
conda install pip
```

After that, pip returns to normal.

Answer (score 2):

pip is not being installed properly on your "user", so try the following :

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

For the current user only:

`easy_install --user pip`

or

`python -m pip install --upgrade --user pip`

The second may give `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`
Even if `which pip` finds the module named pip.
In this case try the `easy_install`

Answer (score 1):

In *some* cases, this can occur because pip was upgraded by the root user, and the upgrade - for some reason - defaults to creating non-all-user-accessible subdirectories and files in the "site-packages" directory.

To check if this is the case, we need [locate the site-packages directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122327/1593077), e.g. with python3, running this command:

```
python -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"])'
```

Now let's check whether there are pip-related subdirs there with problematic permissions:

```
site_pkg_dirs=$(python -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()["purelib"])')
pushd ${site_pkg_dirs}
ls -ld pip*
popd
```

If the output is empty - then this answer won't solve your problem; sorry :-(

But if the output is not empty, e.g.:

```
drwxr-x--- 5 root root 111 Jan 01 00:00 pip
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 170 Jan 01 00:00 pip-21.3.1.dist-info
```

then carefully examine the [permission listing](https://superuser.com/q/945547/122798) on each: If the "all" permission triplet doesn't have `r` and `x` - you need to add those; and since this same problem might be manifested for other packages, let's be more thorough about it:

```
find ${site_pkg_dirs} -type d | chmod a+rx
find ${site_pkg_dirs} -type f | chmod a+r
```

this ensures all subdirectories in your site package directory are readable and recursable, and that all files in those subdirectories are readable. Specifically, this will apply to the pip-related subdirs, which should now look like this when you `ls -l` them:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 111 Jan 01 00:00 pip
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 170 Jan 01 00:00 pip-21.3.1.dist-info
```

This should solve your pip troubles! Let's check: If you now run

```
pip show pip
```

you should get something like :

```
$ pip3.6 show pip
Name: pip
Version: 21.3.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /usr/lib/python/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

possibly with a different version and your own site packages dir.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my virtual environment after upgrade python installation from 3.6 to 3.7 but only on vent globally pip work fine, to solve it I deactivate and delete my virtual environment after recreate again and now is fine, on venv:

```
deactivate
rm -rvf venv
```

and after recreate the virtual environment.
I use mac OS 10.11, and python 3

Answer (score 0):

my solution:
first step like most other answer:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

second, add soft link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it first, and install again ,it will be ok.
for centos:

```
yum remove python-pip
yum install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is adding `import pip` to the script linked to the `pip/pip3` commands.

Firstly, open the file (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/pip`) with your favorite text editor and the sudo mode. For example, I use `sudo vim /usr/local/bin/pip` to open the script file.

You will obtain some file as following:

```
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Afterwards, insert the statement `import pip` just before the `from pip._internal import main` then the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

These often comes from using pip to "update" system installed pip, and/or having multiple pip installs under user.  My solution was to clean out the multiple installed pips under user, reinstall pip repo, then "pip install --user pip" as above.

See: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for an official complete discussion and fixes for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

windows OS：

```
1、download this file：“https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py”，Put it in this（E:\PythonProject\venv\Scripts’（Your virtual environment installation directory）） directory！
2、open ‘Windows PowerShell’
3、cd ‘E:\PythonProject\venv\Scripts’（Your virtual environment installation directory）
4、run cmd ‘py get-pip.py’
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the directory permission for /usr/local/lib/python3.9/ and modify the permission using chown command

```
sudo chown -R centos:centos /usr/local/lib/python3.9/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem because some of my folders got corrupted due to a hard disk failure, due to this the pip_internal folder also got corrupted.
To fix this, I first ran a disk repair restart so that the corrupted folders get removed from the drive, after that I deleted the whole `pip` folder from the site packages (*Python>Lib>site-packages>pip*).

Then I ran this command in terminal: `python -m ensurepip` and it reinstalled the whole pip package. After this pip is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
 py -m install packagename
```

instead of

```
pip install packagename
```

Comment: `python3 -m pip install <package>.whl` worked for me instead

Answer (score 0):

On Mac and MiniConda, I used the following command and it worked:

```
 conda activate /opt/miniconda3 /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda install -p /opt/miniconda3 pip -y
```