# pip install ImportError: No module named _internal

Tags: python, module, importerror

"pip install markdown" giving following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _internal
```

Using Windows. I have installed both python 2.7 and python 3.6 in C:\Python27 and C:\Python36 respectively. Python 2.7 is the default one right now. I am trying to install for python 2.7.

It was working before installing mysql. Don't know if that has anything to do with it. I updated the python 2.7.14 to python 2.7.15. Tried turning off antivirus. Tried to look up the exact error but everyone has slightly different error. Tried uninstalling pip and reinstalling pip. Tried restarting the pc. Tried to look into run.py found nothing. Tried to look for **main**.py by opening pip.exe but it is not opening with idle/sublime. I think it has something to do with user authentication but not sure. There is only one user/administrator on the system.

Comment: Also tried to reinstall python 2.7.14 by using the repair feature

Comment: problem solved..... I uninstalled all python versions and then reinstalled python 2.7, python 3.6 and other packages again ......don't use repair feature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip: no module named \_internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal)