# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package

Tags: python, pip

Newbie question here.
I am teaching myself to code using Automate the Boring Stuff With Python and I'm stuck as I can't seem to set up pip. Here is the error message:

```
C:\Users\Rayanne>pip --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rayanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Rayanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Rayanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package
```

I have tried reinstalling python and followed some tutorials online. Even though I install pip successfully, the same error appears. Have I accidentally deleted the pip._internal module? Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip: no module named _internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal)

Comment: you probably have a file called `pip.py` in your local directory?

Comment: Thank you! I renamed a file named 'pip.py' to 'pip1.py' and now pip works normally in cmd!

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I have a file named 'pip.py' and that was interrupting pip in cmd. I solved the problem simply by renaming said file.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to run pip or the python executable from the installation folder?
For example open the cmd shell in:
`C:\Users\Rayanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`
and execute: `.\python.exe -m pip --version`
or
open the cmd shell in:
`C:\Users\Rayanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts`
and execute: `.\pip.exe --version`

If it is working, you have to check your windows path variable.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for answering! I tried your suggestion and it still shows the same error :(