# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Recently I updated Python version Python 3.9.14 from Python3.6.
I am running django project, so while running it and also while installing any dependencies, getting this error message - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
How to solve this.
Getting the below error for `pip3 version`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

I tried `python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3` , but I got:

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3
```

Thank you

Comment: how did you upgrade  python in your system ? use a virtualenv to run your project

Comment: `pip3` is not a module, ever. I think you confused `python3 -m pip` with the **alias** named `pip3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip: no module named \_internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940813/pip-no-module-named-internal)

Comment: @sahasrara62 isnt it possible to run django project directly without virtual environment ?

Comment: @Gaurav every project should have 1 env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
            # ^ note no 3           ^ in either place
```

since the module is always named `pip`, it's just the command line utility that might be named `pip3`.

Second, if that still fails, you've got a `pip3` installed for a version of Python that does not match the version you get when you run `python3` itself, and that version, for whatever reason, neglected to ship with `pip` by default.

The best solution, if available, is to install your distro's corresponding `pip` (often named something like `python3-pip` or the like). If that fails, you can run:

```
python3 -mensurepip
```

to have Python itself attempt to fix up/install the `pip` it should have shipped with (you may want to run this with `sudo` or the like so it can be installed globally).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this solution previously and it works:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Comment: This isn't typically needed on modern Python; it always ships with the `ensurepip` module so even if `pip` itself isn't included, `python3 -mensurepip` will fix up `pip` (and can do so without relying on Internet resources, though without them, it can't upgrade from the embedded `pip` to the most modern version).

Comment: You solution is an alternative solution which could have been posted as an answer to the question. Both solution works!

Comment: @OlasimboArigbabu , I tried this but it couldnt solve the issue. I am still getting the error.