# Tried everything still getting the error No module named 'pip.download'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, build, setuptools

python3 -m build --sdist --wheel --outdir dist/

- Creating virtualenv isolated environment...
- Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools >= 40.8.0, wheel)
- Getting build dependencies for sdist...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.download'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ciasto/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/ciasto/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/home/ciasto/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 287, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
        return hook(config_settings)
      File "/tmp/build-env-h_1fvjgg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 328, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
        return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
      File "/tmp/build-env-h_1fvjgg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
        self.run_setup()
      File "/tmp/build-env-h_1fvjgg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "/tmp/build-env-h_1fvjgg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
        exec(code, locals())
      File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.download'
    
    ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
```

I tried to update the pip

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54851781/3311276

and tried:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1026848

I basically do not get any error when I do

```
pip -V
pip 23.3.1 from /home/ciasto/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```